# Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, interface

Alguém pode dar uma explicação prática sobre motivos para se usar interfaces e por que elas são úteis para nós desenvolvedores?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As interfaces são úteis porque elas estabelecem *contratos*. Se uma classe implementar uma interface você vai poder referenciar instancias da classe pela interface tendo somente acesso aos membros definidos na interface. Isso significa basicamente, que você **garante** que a classe apresentará um certo comportamento sem que se saiba a priori como esse comportamento é implementado. Por exemplo, pense na interface `IComparable` do C#, ela determina que classes que a implementam possuam um método de comparação. Essa ideia pode ser usada por exemplo para construir uma classe de árvore binária como mostrado no livro Microsoft Visual C# 2010 passo a passo, pois assinando essa interface você garante que existe alguma forma de comparar objetos daquela classe.

Por isso falamos que interfaces estabelecem contratos: uma classe implementar uma interface é como assinar um contrato, ela promete que vai ter aquela funcionalidade. Isso permite que você obedeça alguns dos principios SOLID e escreva códigos que são pouco acoplados e com alta coesão.

O primeiro princípio, Single Responsibility Principle, diz que cada classe deve ter uma única responsabilidade: fazer algo e fazer aquilo bem. Mas várias vezes pra fazer algo uma classe tem dependências, por exemplo gerenciar dados ou enviar e-mails. Para respeitar esse princípio, essas dependências não podem ser codificadas na classe, elas devem ser codificadas em outras classes e então usadas na classe inicial.

O problema disso é que se você instanciar as dependências dentro da classe que você está trabalhando você vai acoplar essas classes. Se você precisar mudar o serviço de e-mails ou de dados, você vai ter que mudar lá também e isso pode não ser interessante e implicar em muito mais trabalho do que o necessário, que era só trocar um serviço.

O último principio do SOLID que fala sobre isso, ele é o Dependency Inversion Principle e ele diz em resumo: "Dependa em abstrações e não em implementações concretas". Isso significa basicamente, que se as dependencias de um de seus componentes são instancias concretas vai ficar mais dificil pra você manter o software, você vai ter que mexer em um código que está muito acoplado.

Um bom exemplo é o padrão de repositórios para acesso a dados. Você cria uma interface, no caso abaixo em C#

```java
public interface IRepositorio<T>
{
    void Adicionar(T entidade);
    void Atualizar(T entidade);
    void Excluir(T entidade);
    IQueryable<T> ListarTudo();
    T ProcurarPorID(int id);
}
```

Quando você precisar de acesso a dados para uma certa entidade `T` você usa uma implementação concreta dessa interface, mas referenciada por ela. Isso significa que você tem um serviço que *promete* que permite realizar todas essas operações, mas não diz nem sequer como.

Daí em outro assembly você pode implementar como quiser, Entity Framework, NHibernate, ou etc, e no fim das contas, para mudar a implementação você só tem que mudar em um lugar. Claro, pra você usar na prática, dizer qual implementação usar para qual interface existem técnicas como Injeção de Dependência. O principal a entender é que as interfaces servem para prometer funcionalidades.

Em resumo: Interfaces são contratos que te ajudam a escrever códigos com baixo acoplamento e alta coesão.

Comment: Outro motivo principal é a possibilidade de 'simular' herança múltipla, já que tudo que foi dito aqui cabe para classes abstratas.

Comment: Achei a explicação bem simples, objetiva e ao mesmo tempo completa.
Eu pessoalmente vejo classes como circuitos você pode emendar um no outro e fazer uma solda ali, ou então você solda soquets e conecta com plugues (que no caso são interfaces) o que te permite desplugar uma classe e plugar outra sem ter que soldar tudo de novo.

Answer (score 26):

Interfaces devem, como o nome diz, prover interfaces para a manipulação de objetos. Se um grupo de objetos diferentes tem um mesmo tipo de ação necessária, você implementa uma interface em todos esses objetos.

Vou dar um exemplo em C#. Considere essas três classes:

```cs
class Cachorro
{
    public string Latir() { return "Au au"; }
}

class Gato
{
    public string Miar() { return "Miau"; }
}

class Vaca
{
    public string Mugir() { return "Muu"; }
}
```

Eu sei, bem infantil, mas vai ser útil pra ilustrar o problema. Agora vamos ao meio de nosso super sistema que tem um módulo que tem uma lista de animais e precisa saber que barulho ele faz. Como fazemos isso sem interfaces?

```cs
List<object> animais = GetAnimais(); // Animais podem ser cachorros, gatos ou vacas, nunca se sabe
foreach (var animal in animais)
{
    var cachorro = animal as Cachorro;
    if (cachorro != null) cachorro.Latir();

    var gato = animal as Gato;
    if (gato != null) gato.Miar();

    var vaca = animal as Vaca;
    if (vaca != null) vaca.Mugir();
}
```

O código funciona. Mas se você trabalhar pra algum lugar tipo o Ibama, você vai ter que fazer a conversão e o null-check pra cada tipo de animal necessário, e podem ser milhares. Ter milhares de linhas de código é muito não-legal quando se pode evitar.

Então, vamos reescrever nossos animais, e colocar uma interface neles!

```cs
interface IAnimal
{
    string Falar();
}

class Cachorro : IAnimal
{
    public string Latir() { return "Au au"; }
    public string IAnimal.Falar() { return Latir(); }
}

class Gato : IAnimal
{
    public string Miar() { return "Miau"; }
    public string IAnimal.Falar() { return Miar(); }
}

class Vaca : IAnimal
{
    public string Mugir() { return "Muu"; }
    public string IAnimal.Falar() { return Mugir(); }
}
```

Agora, aquela utilização de antes vira isso:

```cs
List<IAnimal> animais = GetAnimais();
foreach (var animal in animais) animal.Falar();
```

Que terá o mesmo efeito. Assim você também pode criar 800 novos animais, e só terá que fazer a implementação dele como um IAnimal; não precisará mexer aonde você usa seu método `Falar`.

Outro ponto positivo é que trocando `object` por `IAnimal`, você tem um pouco mais de tipagem segura.

Comment: Muito bacana e lúdico esse exemplo.

Answer (score 5):

Leia um pouco sobre padrões de projetos que você vai entender muito bem. Mas lá vai um exemplo básico.

```java
public interface RepositorioCliente {
  public void inserir(Cliente cliente);
}

public class RepositorioClienteMysql implements RepositorioCliente {

  public void inserir(Cliente cliente) {
  //faz lógica de salvar
  }

}
```

Quando você for usar a classe repositório, você não vai chamá-la diretamente. Você vai instanciar a interface.

```java
RepositorioCliente repositorio = new RepositorioClienteMysql();
```

Se você precisar mudar de banco de dados, todos os métodos em comum, a nova classe responsável por salvar no banco de dados terá obrigatoriamente que implementar. E você só vai precisar mudar a instância.

```java
RepositorioCliente repositorio = new RepositorioClienteNovoBanco();
```

E claro, as classes devem implementar a interface de repositório.

Answer (score 4):

Quando você deseja que dois tipos distintos tenham o mesmo comportamento.

Isso fica visível quando temos uma detecção de padrões de comportamentos entre tipos distintos, mas que segundo esses padrões poderiam ser de uma mesma família lógica. Um exemplo é quando você tiver em seu código dois tipos distintos como Gato e Cachorro, mas detectando semelhanças como o fato dos dois se moverem, emitirem sons e serem animais domésticos, mas note que cada um o faz de uma maneira específica..

Nesse caso desenhamos um tipo `Animal` onde definimos os padrões entre todos os subtipos da classe (`Gato`, `Cachorro`, `Galinha`) como `Andar()`, `Falar()`.

E implementamos todos os subtipos de acordo com o seu tipo de expressão expecífica desses padrões:

```
Animal: Andar() {} Falar(){}
```

`Gato` é um `Animal` logo

```
Andar() { 'anda rápido'} 
Falar() { 'Miau' }
```

`Cachorro` é um `Animal`, logo

```
Andar() {'anda desajeitado' } 
Falar() { 'Au au' }
```

Note que ao definir `Animal` nós não sabemos como os animais a serem implementados andam ou falam. Nós só vamos saber para cada subtipo específico que o implementar.

Essa prática de composição de tipos é muito útil em OOP e sempre que se detectar um padrão entre vários tipos existe um ganho na reutilização,simplificação e elegância do código

No seu código você pode sempre se referenciar ao grupo como `Animal`, ou o supertipo, e dessa forma reutilizar os métodos que de outra forma teriam que ser feitos um para cada animal. diminuindo a reutilização do seu código:

- `AdicionarAnimal(Animal a)`
  adiciona todos os animais (Gato, Galinha, Cachorro.. e futuros)
- `RemoverAnimal(Animal a)`
  remove todos os animais

Imaginou você ter que criar um método desses para cada animal?

`AdicionarGalinha`... `AdicionarCachorro`.. .

Por isso essa composição de tipos ajuda e muito na reutilização de lógica, e na diminuição da complexidade do código.

Answer (score 3):

Entendo que a questão já foi respondida anteriormente, mas um caso bem simples é você imaginar um método para enviar um alerta quando uma tarefa deve ser executada.

Criamos uma interface: (simples para demonstração)

```
public interface IAlerta
{
    void Envia();
}
```

E uma classe que usa:

```
public class Tarefa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public IAlerta Alerta { get; set; }
}
```

Podemos ter diversas versões pra IAlerta, nesse exemplo um alerta pode ser enviado por e-mail ou por sms, é justamente nesse cenário que as interfaces se fazem necessárias. A classe Tarefa não precisa conhecer a implementação necessária para enviar um sms ou e-mail, ela apenas utilizará o método Alerta.Envia(); que será acionado por polimorfismo.

Vamos simular a implementação das duas versões de IAlerta

```
public class AlertaEmail : IAlerta
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public void Envia(string mensagem)
    {
        // aqui implementamos o envio por e-mail
    }
}

public class AlertaSMS : IAlerta
{
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public void Envia(string mensagem)
    {
        // aqui implementamos o envio por sms
    }
}
```

Vejamos exemplo de uso das 2 implementações de alerta em tarefa

```
AlertaEmail alertaEmail = new AlertaEmail() { Email = "jaspion@japan.jp" };
AlertaSMS alertaSMS = new AlertaSMS() { Telefone = "99 9999 9999" };

Tarefa tarefa = new Tarefa();

tarefa.Alerta = alertaEmail;
tarefa.Alerta.Envia("Ops");

tarefa.Alerta = alertaSMS;
tarefa.Alerta.Envia("Ops");
```

Nosso sistema de tarefas funciona normalmente sem precisar se "preocupar" em como será enviado o alerta, nem como é implementado internamente, apenas espera uma instância que implementa a interface IAlerta.

Supondo que quiséssemos uma nova versão de alerta que faz envia um tweet, não precisaríamos alterar em nada nosso sistema de tarefas. Apenas esperaríamos uma implementação de IAlert que fizesse o isso, que veja bem, poderia ser implementada por qualquer pessoa, inclusive terceiros. Só precisaríamos que enviar a interface e pedir o código implementado.

```
public class AlertaTwitter : IAlerta
{
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public void Envia(string mensagem)
    {
        // aqui implementamos um post no twitter
    }
}
```

E na nossa tarefa, receberíamos uma instância de um objeto da classe AlertaTwitter.

```
AlertaTwitter alertaTwitter = new AlertaTwitter() { Twitter = "@jaspion" };

tarefa.Alerta = alertaTwitter;
```

Existe outros cenários bem parecidos com esse que podem utilizar, como um sistema de logs, você teria uma Interface ILog com um método GravaLog por exemplo e que poderia ser implementado de diversas maneiras, como gravar um arquivo de texto, gravar num banco de dados, enviar um e-mail, dentre outros.

Answer (score 2):

Devemos utilizar a construção de linguagem interface, quando precisamos definir o comportamento de uma família de objetos, que não possuem nenhuma implementação em comum.

Por exemplo, precisamos definir uma família de objetos iteráveis. Nesse caso, podemos ter iteradores de objetos vindos da base de dados, podemos ter iteradores de dados de um CSV. Podemos ter iteradores diretórios, podemos ter iteradores de N coisas diferentes, cuja implementação não é compartilhável. Nesse caso, quando não temos implementação em comum, utilizamos a construção de linguagem interface.

Demonstrando isso no PHP, faremos de conta que precisamos de uma lista de usuários, não importando de onde virá esses dados. O código poderia ser da seguinte maneira:

```php
interface DataUsers {
    public function getUsers();
}

class RenderUsers {
    private $datausers;

    public function __construct(DataUsers $datausers){
        $this->datausers = $datausers;
    }

    public function listUsers(){
        return $this->datausers->getUsers();
    }
}

class MySQLUsers implements DataUsers {
    public function getUsers(){
        // Aqui vai a implementação para o MySQL
    }
}

class XMLUsers implements DataUsers {
    public function getUsers(){
        // Aqui vai a implementação para o XML
    }
}

class WebServiceUsers implements DataUsers {
    public function getUsers(){
        // Aqui vai a implementação para um WebService qualquer
    }
}
```

Tendo em vista que temos uma interface, a implementação poderá variar pois sabemos que o retorno será o mesmo sempre, independente do input.

O uso ficaria assim:

```php
// Se você quer os dados vindos de um banco MySQL
$mysqlUsers = new MySQLUsers();
$usuarios = new RenderUsers( $mysqlUsers );
echo $usuarios->listUsers();

// Se você quer os dados vindos de um XML
$xmlUsers = new XMLUsers();
$usuarios = new RenderUsers( $xmlUsers );
echo $usuarios->listUsers();

// Se você quer os dados vindos de um WebService qualquer
$webServiceUsers = new WebServiceUsers();
$usuarios = new RenderUsers( $webServiceUsers );
echo $usuarios->listUsers();
```

O importante na Orientação a Objetos é sempre programar para a interface, independente de onde virá os dados, o que é irrelevante.

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria que interfaces sao uteis pois permite aos objectos dependerem de uma definicao de uma classe e nao de uma implementacao de uma classe em concreto. Desta forma conseguimos "injectar/attribuir" em objectos qualquer implementacao que siga a definicao desta classe.