# Por que em algumas situações if's são considerados ruins?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, if

Li em alguns lugares que não é recomendado o uso exagerado do `if`, pois ele torna seu código difícil de ler e de dar manutenção, logo não é uma boa prática.

O que seria o uso exagerado de `if` em um código? Quais são as boas práticas em um código para evitar muitos `if`s?

**EDIT**

A idéia da *campanha anti if* na verdade não é exterminar o *if*, e sim estimular o uso correto da programação orientada a objetos, que deixa o código mais limpo e de fácil manutenção. A minha pergunta é na verdade saber como eu devo substituir os zilhões de *if* s por uma boa diagramação de classes. Que conceitos da programação orientada a objetos são utilizados para atingir tal objetivo?

Entre outras palavras: Porque trocar o condicional imperativo, pelo polimorfismo ou outra forma que facilite o entendimento e organização do código?

Fonte(s) de motivação / leitura:

[Campanha anti if](http://rodrigonormandia.com/?p=108%5D)

[Anti if campaign(Inglês)](http://www.antiifcampaign.com/)

Comment: É a idéia geral de trocar ifs por uma hierarquia de classes. Vai haver casos onde vale a pena e casos onde não vale. Mesmo com OO o if sempre vai existir, pois em algum lugar você vai ter que escolher que tipo de objeto instanciar.

Comment: Pois é, não é uma campanha anti-if, mas uma campanha usar OO corretamente...

Comment: existe uma [versão em inglês](http://www.antiifcampaign.com/) da campanha anti if (ou o nosso é uma versão do deles?) que explica com uma riqueza de detalhes o motivo da _campanha_. Seria legal ter essas explicações e exemplos em português.

Comment: @Math Não gostei do site da campanha (em inglês). Não tem um texto de justificativa objetivo e fácil de achar! Ou vc tem um link direto? Eu não achei.

Comment: @bfavaretto a parte que justifica é a aba [Get Started](http://www.antiifcampaign.com/get-started.html). Eu pelo menos gostei, talvez por ter me auto-identificado bem rapidamente, rs..

Comment: O excesso de If's além de aumentar a complexidade do código, aumenta a dificuldade no entendimento e na hora de fazer futuras manutenções. Se você estiver utilizando conceitos como a Orientação a Objetos, existem formas de suprir um eventual encadeamento de If's. Dá uma lida nesse artigo aqui que eu acho ele bem legal. Já está há um bom tempo nos meus favoritos. :)

http://blog.caelum.com.br/como-nao-aprender-orientacao-a-objetos-o-excesso-de-ifs/

Comment: Creio ser mais uma questão subjetiva e de gosto pessoal. Em alguns casos o polimorfismo é preferencial (quando esse comportamento diferente é mesmo algo intelectualmente diferenciável em termos de ser uma classe distinta), mas isso não é regra geral. Por exemplo: a classe pessoa: tem pessoas que gostam de rock, outras de samba, etc.. É correto criar uma classe para cada comportamento diferente? Uma pergunta mais adequada: "Como rotear código de modo eficiente"

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Começo citando um comentário dado na [pergunta original do SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554180/why-is-the-if-statement-considered-evil):

> if statements are evil in the way hammers are evil. Some people might
>   misuse them, but they're an essential tool. –  Dominic Rodger Oct 12
>   '09 at 12:08

Em tradução livre: "Comandos IF são tão demoníacos como martelos. Algumas pessoas fazem mal uso deles, mas são ferramentas essenciais."

Esse comentário faz sentido na medida de que sem uma estrutura de controle de fluxo simplesmente não é possível se construir um programa de computador que seja útil, afinal a resolução de problemas depende de **decisões** em algum escopo.

Muito embora os IFs sejam realmente elementos fundamentais em qualquer linguagem de programação, as linha de argumentação que classificam os comandos IF como ruins - como a campanha Anti-IF citada na pergunta - não são tão dogmáticas como parecem. Como indicado no próprio site da Campanha Anti-IF, seu lema é esse:

> The goal of the Anti-IF Campaign is to raise awareness of effective
>   use of software design principles and practices, first of all removing
>   bad, dangerous IFs.

Em tradução livre: "O objetivo da campanha Anti-IF é sensibilizar os desenvolvedores sobre o uso efetivo dos princípios e práticas de projeto de software, em especial a remoção de IFs ruins ou inseguros."

Apesar de usarem uma estratégia de marketing arrojada (ao dizer que o IF é *demoníaco* - ou *evil* no original em inglês), o que essas campanhas propõem é que se tome cuidado com a utilização de condicionais em situações em que eles podem estar sendo mal utilizados ou até mesmo serem perigosos no sentido de dificultar a manutenção do código.

O exemplo clássico é baseado em uma única classe ([a fonte original](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) desse código merece um +1 só por ser [claramente](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2BfSixvcdc) [inspirada](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBTrcLsoa_c) nas [piadas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSC6RayVSqI) do grupo britânico de humor [Monty Python](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python)!):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```java
public class Passaro {

    private double m_dVelocidadeBase;
    private double m_dFatorPeso;
    private int m_iNumCocos;
    private boolean m_bPregado;
    private double m_dVoltagemChoque;
    private TipoPassaro m_eTipo;

    . . .

    double getVelocidade() {
        switch (m_eTipo) {
            case TipoPassaro.ANDORINHA_EUROPEIA:
                return m_dVelocidadeBase;
            case TipoPassaro.ANDORINHA_AFRICANA:
                return m_dVelocidadeBase - (m_dFatorPeso * m_iNumCocos);
            case TipoPassaro.PAPAGAIO_AZUL_NORUEGUES:
                return m_bPregado ? 0 : m_dVelocidadeBase * m_dVoltagemChoque;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException ("Oops! Essa parte do código não deveria ser executada.");
    }

    . . .

}
```

Nesse exemplo, a classe `Passaro` pode representar diferentes tipos de instâncias de pássaros (entre elas, as andorinhas Européia e Africana e o papagaio Azul Norueguês), e por isso o método `getVelocidade` tem uma complexidade grande relacionada às diferentes formas com que a velocidade do pássaro é calculada com relação ao seu tipo. Essa complexidade está expressa na necessidade de se ter uma série de decisões (vários `if` ou, igualmente, um `switch`) com relação ao tipo de pássaro. Se, existirem outros métodos nessa classe (como, por exemplo, `getPiado`, `getFome`, etc), muito provavelmente eles também deverão ter IFs para tratar as diferenças, e a complexidade da solução e dificuldade de manutenção apenas aumentarão (pois, se um novo tipo de pássaro precisar ser adicionado, todos os lugares/métodos com IFs precisarão ser alterados).

A forma sugerida de contornar o problema é decorrente do uso apropriado dos conceitos de herança, abstração e polimorfismo da Orientação a Objetos. Ao invés de ter uma única classe `Passaro` e instanciá-la para cada diferente tipo de pássaro, pode-se torná-la em uma classe abstrata (isto é, que não pode/deve ser instanciada) ou em uma interface, para que contenha as propriedades e assinaturas de métodos padrão entre os diferentes tipos de pássaros. Pode-se então criar novas classes, uma para cada tipo de pássaro propriamente dito (classes `AndorinhaEuropeia`, `AndorinhaAfricana` e `PapagaioAzulNoruegues`, no exemplo), de modo que elas herdem da classe-base `Passaro` e implementem as especificidades de cada tipo em seus próprios métodos sobrescritos.

O resultado (também baseado na fonte original referida anteriormente) seria o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```java
public abstract class Passaro {

    private double m_dVelocidadeBase;

    . . .

    double getVelocidade() {
        return m_dVelocidadeBase;
    }

    . . .

}

public class AndorinhaEuropeia extends Passaro {

    . . .

    // Apenas um exemplo, pois é desnecessária a reimplementação nesse caso, 
    // uma vez que ela não altera o método original da classe pai.
    double getVelocidade() {
        return super.getVelocidade();
    }

    . . .

}

public class AndorinhaAfricana extends Passaro {

    private double m_dFatorPeso;
    private int m_iNumCocos;

    . . .

    double getVelocidade() {
        return super.getVelocidade() - (m_dFatorPeso * m_iNumCocos);
    }

    . . .

}

public class PapagaioAzulNoruegues extends Passaro {

    private boolean m_bPregado;
    private double m_dVoltagemChoque;

    . . .

    double getVelocidade() {
        return m_bPregado ? 0 : super.getVelocidade() * m_dVoltagemChoque;
    }

    . . .

}
```

Dessa forma, os IFs não são necessários porque cada classe específica (herdadas de `Passaro`) implementa sua própria forma de calcular a velocidade. Além disso, o polimorfismo da orientação a objetos permite tratar os passaros de maneira generalizada, de forma que é possível lidar com as diferenças sem precisar fazer IFs explícitos:

```java
Passaro oUmPassaro = new AndorinhaAfricana();
Passaro oOutroPassaro = new PapagaioAzulNoruegues();
Passaro oPassaroQualquer = fabricanteDePassaros.criaUmPassaro(); // Método independente de criação

System.out.println(oUmPassaro.getVelocidade());
System.out.println(oOutroPassaro.getVelocidade());
System.out.println(oPassaroQualquer.getVelocidade());
```

Se compararmos as duas abordagens considerando uma eventual futura necessidade de se adicionar um novo tipo de pássaro (digamos, o Tucano), que tem suas próprias formas de calcular a velocidade (tamanho do bico talvez influencie?), notaremos que na primeira abordagem será necessário adicionar um novo tipo à enumeração, e será principalmente necessário adicionar um novo caso (isto é, um novo IF) ao método `getVelocidade` da classe `Passaro`. Na segunda abordagem, a classe `Passaro` não precisa ser alterada, bastando apenas criar uma nova classe `Tucano` e herdá-la de `Passaro`.

Essa distinção não apenas influencia no montante de código a ser escrito (e aqui alguém poderia argumentar que adicionar um IF é bem mais fácil - e usa menos linhas de código - do que criar toda uma nova classe) e a facilidade de manutenção (novamente, alguém poderia argumentar que é mais fácil localizar onde alterar se todo o código estiver em uma só classe), mas em outras questões importantes. Por exemplo, em linguagens como C++, recompilar o código após uma alteração em uma classe utilizada em vários locais causa uma tempo de compilação maior (pois mais dependências são recompiladas). Se a abordagem 2 for utilizada, os arquivos que dependem das demais classes (outros pássaros que não o Tucano) não precisam ser recompilados. Deve ser claro que isso tem impacto também nos testes já realizados. Quanto mais localizada é uma alteração, menos chance ela tem de causar defeitos (*bugs*) de regressão.

Note ainda que esse exemplo é bem específico. Nesse cenário, as diferenças do cálculo da velocidade decorrem de *comportamentos distintos* entre os objetos, o que por si só já indica que faz muito sentido construir uma hierarquia de classe. Isso quer dizer que, além dos benefícios argumentados o código resultante é potencialmente de um entendimento mais simples e claro.

Por isso, de forma alguma isso quer dizer que o comando IF é malígno. Apenas que seu uso em exemplos como esse não parece ser a forma mais indicada de resolução do problema, especialmente em linguagens orientadas a objetos. Seguramente pode-se fornecer exemplos em que utilizar uma sequência de IFs é mais direto e simples do que construir toda uma estrutura de classes. O que me ocorre neste momento é um exemplo de exibição de mensagens de erro:

```java
public void displayErrorMessage(Error e) {
    if(e.Type() == IOError.FILE_IS_READ_ONLY) {
        // Mensagem de aviso, solicitando fechar outras aplicações e tentar novamente
    }
    else if(e.Type() == IOError.FILE_EXISTS) {
        // Mensagem de aviso importante, solicitando anuência
    }
    else if(e.Type() == IOError.ERROR_WRITING_DATA) {
        // Mensagem crítica, informando impossibilidade de gravação
    }
    . . .
}
```

Claro que seria possível construir essa mesma decisão por meio de uma hierarquia de classes, mas isso não parece realmente necessário nesse exemplo, especialmente se a classe `Error` é nativa da linguagem. Ainda que a classe seja definida pelo próprio programador (em que se poderia herdar os diversos tipos de erros e especializar um método getErrorMessage de forma similar ao exemplificado anteriormente), as questões que cabem aqui são: quantas novas mensagens de erro de IO poderão surgir no futuro? há realmente alguma possibilidade de alteração em que os IFs irão realmente prejudicar o entendimento ou a manutenção desse código?

Pra encerrar, eu gostaria de citar [esse outro exemplo](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/avoiding-fors-anti-if-campaign.html) em que a campanha é por se evitar o uso de FORs. No exemplo citado, propõem-se trocar esse código:

```c#
public class Department {
    private List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<Resource>();

    public void addResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resources.add(resource);
    }

    public void printSlips() {

        for (Resource resource : resources) { 
            if(resource.lastContract().deadline().after(new Date())) { 
                System.out.println(resource.name()); 
                System.out.println(resource.salary());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

por esse:

```c#
public class Department {
    private List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<Resource>();

    public void addResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resources.add(resource);
    }

    public void printSlips() {
        new ResourceOrderedCollection(this.resources).select(new InForcePredicate()).forEachDo(new PrintSlip());
    }
}
```

com a criação de três classes e duas interfaces. O problema apontado é que originalmente o método `printSlips` *faz mais do que deveria*, porque faz uma iteração entre os recursos (o `for`), faz a seleção de que recursos devem ser impressos (o `if`) e tem a responsabilidade de imprimir os itens componentes de cada recurso (os diversos `System.out.println`). A solução cria uma classe para conter e iterar sobre os recursos, uma para definir a seleção e uma para imprimir recursos.

Essa alternativa é bacana, mas há outras. Por exemplo, a própria classe `Resource` poderia ter um método `toString` que já imprime o que deve ser impresso, e o método `printSlips` poderia receber como parâmetro uma instância de classe para verificação das condições de impressão (isto é, um filtro).

De todas as formas, qual é a melhor? Leia o post original e tire as suas próprias conclusões. Novamente, isso não quer dizer que o FOR seja maléfico, demoníaco ou ruim. :)

Comment: Acho que até você aprendeu ou pelo menos consolidou melhor algo sobre isso :) Nestes momentos podemos mostrar objetivamente (ou quase) como algo deve ser usado. Claro que sempre pode haver polêmica. Mas não precisamos de respostas absolutas, precisamos algo que ensine como as coisas funcionam, como elas devem ser pensadas. Mesmo que alguém discorde, a resposta é muito boa. E vou repetir algo aqui que tenho orgulho: temos uma resposta aqui muito melhor que no SO original :)

Comment: De fato. Valeu pelo puxão de orelha. :)

Comment: Fiquei com preguiça de ler tudo, mas +1 por ter achado um exemplo que cita Monty Python sem ser de Python. Afinal, "Um rei precisa saber dessas coisas".

Answer (score 19):

Olha, não tem assim nenhum tipo de Regra ou Padrão para essas coisas, porém **parando para pensar**, você consegue identificar o melhor método para programar, como o @IgorCarvalho disse, isto é "feeling" ou seja, é como se fosse um sentimento, que seria este tal **pensamento**, que seria o melhor método de fazer em visão programática, visando a performance, visando o entendimendo do código e visando poucas linhas, soluções objetivas. Porém tem alguns conceitos básicos que você pode pegar que são o seguintes:

## Exemplos

> Suponhamos que você não tenha uma função de mês por extenso traduzida em sua linguagem de programação, por exemplo em javascript(minha linguagem mais usada):

Este caso seria utilizando o `if`(o mes em javascript é `zero-indexed` começa do 0):

```js
var mes = 1;
if (mes == 0)
  var strMes = "Janeiro";
if (mes == 1)
  var strMes = "Fevereiro";
if (mes == 2)
  var strMes = "Março";
if (mes == 3)
  var strMes = "Abril";
if (mes == 4)
  var strMes = "Mario";
if (mes == 5)
  var strMes = "Junho";
if (mes == 6)
  var strMes = "Julho";
if (mes == 7)
  var strMes = "Agosto";
if (mes == 8)
  var strMes = "Setembro";
if (mes == 9)
  var strMes = "Outubro";
if (mes == 10)
  var strMes = "Novembro";
if (mes == 11)
  var strMes = "Dezembro";
```

Ao invés de passar esse trabalho todo porque não fazer o seguinte:

```js
var aryMes = ["Janeiro","Fevereiro","Março","Abril","Maio","Junho","Julho","Agosto","Setembro","Outubro","Novembro","Dezembro"];
var mes = 1; //1 é fevereiro no date().getMonth() do javascript.
var strMes = aryMes[mes];
```

Sabe, é muito melhor, é bem menor e poupa muitas linhas de código, mas isso você tem que aprender com o tempo, de acordo com quanto tempo que você programa, e com qual intensidade, você vai ver soluções diferentes para problemas que você vai dizer:

> "Não acredito que eu poderia ter feito em uma linha o que eu fiz em 25"

ou então:

> "Nossa, nem imaginava que existia esta função que fazia tudo pra mim"

Basicamente, você tem que aprender com o tempo, porém pra fazer este exemplo eu pensei em uma coisa:

> "São 12 valores diferentes, quando há muitos valores, devo usar um `array`, pois `if` e `switch(case)` me dariam muitas linhas de código."

Este pode ser um bom pensamento, porém cada programador tem seus métodos de fazer, muita coisa é lógica, tipo tá na cara, como o exemplo que eu te dei, pra mim está na cara que era pra fazer isso, porém pra ti pode não estar.

A dica que eu te dou é continue programando, se informe, aprenda mais, veja soluções novas para coisas que você faz como rotineiras, aperfeiçoe seu código e aprenda constantemente.

## Respondendo diretamente ao título da pergunta:

> Porque em algumas situações if's são considerados ruins?

Porque eles podem se tornar difíceis de entender, aos olhos de outro programador, ou até mesmo de você depois de um tempo, também porque eles dependendo da maneira que foram usados, porem reduzir a performance do seu algoritmo, podem consumir muito mais linhas de código do que o usual, por isso tem que tomar cuidado pra saber onde utilizar, pois uma condição só deve ser utilizada quando você não tem outra opção, pois a função do `if` é apenas para condição, se você conseguir achar uma saída para não utilizar um `if` e não ter que escrever mais código por isso, você se saiu bem. Pois há casos que o uso do `if` é inutil como por exemplo:

```js
var saldo  = 50;
var divida = 50;
if ((saldo - divida) <= 0)
  alert('Desculpe, Seu saldo acabou.');
else
  alert('Seu saldo está em:'+(saldo - divida)+' reais');
```

**Neste caso você poderia ter feito assim:**

```js
var saldo  = 50;
var divida = 50;
alert('Você tem um saldo de:'+(saldo - divida)+' reais);
```

Note que você não precisava do if, se você pensar, poderá encontrar meios de não usa-lo mas claro, há casos que `if` serão ótimos, porém haverá alguns que serão desnecessários ou até ruins, caso eles forem motivo para redução de performance, ou aumento de linhas de código ou programação desnecessária ou dificil de entender.

## Algumas citações:

> "Não adianta ser inteligente, sem ter sabedoria."
>
> "Quanto mais preguiçoso você é, melhores vão ser suas soluções para problemas."
>
> "Melhor pensar e fazer bem feito do que fazer rápido e ter que refazer 5 vezes."

Bem... resumindo é isso, boa sorte em sua jornada, programador !

> "Que a força esteja com você - Mestre Yoda"

Comment: O problema de argumentar com "bom senso" é que cada um tem o seu. Ou seja, dizer para usar o bom senso, é mais ou menos dizer "use o que você achar melhor". O que precisamos é de critérios objetivos. Partes da sus resposta dizem isso. Mas sempre que eu vejo "use o bom senso" eu leio "faça o que você achar melhor". Afinal o bom senso é isso mesmo, uma opinião, honesta, é verdade, do que a pessoa **acha**.

Comment: Tens razão sobre isso, mas o Bom Senso que eu quis dizer não foi para este sentido, foi para o sentido que é realmente melhor e não pessoal de cada um, você sabe alguma outra palavra que encaixaria melhor?

Comment: Não, eu só consigo substituir isso com "faça o que achar melhor" ou "use seu próprio julgamento para decidir". Mas nenhum deles é um critério claro.

Comment: _Feeling_ é importante e vem com a experiência, mas até mesmo programadores experientes podem ser orgulhosos e acharem que fazem "da melhor maneira possível", quando na verdade podem estar deixando boas idéias de lado em prol apenas de suas experiências pessoais. Talvez existam critérios objetivos para refatorar código. Por exemplo, mesmo já achando meu código "bonito" (segundo critérios pessoais), no momento estou lendo [este material](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring), que inclusive fala sobre if's (Replace Conditional with Polymorphism) e ele está me abrindo os olhos para muitas coisas.

Comment: `estou lendo este material, que inclusive fala sobre if's (Replace Conditional with Polymorphism) e ele está me abrindo os olhos para muitas coisas`. Cara, fiquei muito feliz de ler isso!

Comment: @bigown, na verdade, eu estava lhe perguntando se você sabe alguma palavra que demonstre "Faça do jeito melhor, não melhor para você, mas melhor em questões de programação"

Comment: E eu disse que não sei de nada melhor. Não vejo problema na expressão, e sim na intenção dela. ter bom senso é senso comum. Todos acham que é bom ter bom senso. Mas dizer "tenha bom senso" não quer dizer nada que alguém não saiba. Dizer o que seria o bom senso no caso específico, ajudaria mais. Mesmo que alguém discorde. Embora colocar opiniões aqui não seja o ideal, dizer "siga a sua opinião" é menos ideal ainda. Em partes você mostrou algo útil, apesar de que eu acho que substituir um `if` por um *lookup* não é exatamente o que a pergunta está falando. Já temos 2 respostas bem interessantes.

Comment: @bigown , editei minha pergunta, agora me expliquei melhor no começo. Mas a pergunta está perguntando porque usar if é ruim, eu disse que é ruim pelo fato de consumir mais linhas de código, por se tornar menos eficiente em questão de performance, e também por ter dificil entendimento.

Comment: @Math É, mas tem que tomar cuidado com ["refactor syndrome"](http://www.makinggoodsoftware.com/2011/03/27/the-obsession-with-beautiful-code-the-refactor-syndrome/). :)

Comment: @PauloRoberto Eu acho a sua resposta bacana porque ela apresenta uma comparação em que há realmente uma diferença objetiva (desempenho) ao usar ou não IFs: fazer uma sequência (no pior caso, dezembro) de 12 comparações provavelmente leva mais tempo do que endereçar uma posição em uma matriz (seja essa diferença significativa ou não). Mas o que os demais já apontaram é que além desse argumento, outros como "... é muito melhor, é bem menor e poupa muitas linhas de código", são meramente opinativos. Menos/mais linhas não necessariamente implica em qualidade/defeito ou clareza/nebulosidade.

Comment: Com certeza porém é uma resposta válida para a pergunta 
"Por que em algumas situações ifs sao considerados ruins?" eu apenas disse alguns deles :)

Comment: @PauloRoberto Sim, também acho válida. :)

Comment: Eu ia justo dizer que switch não é tão melhor que if, mas esta resposta mostrou a elegante construção com a lista -- que com algum empenho também pode ser usada em C e C++.

Comment: `"Quanto mais preguiçoso você é, melhores vão ser suas soluções para problemas."`, qual a fonte @PauloRoberto? Vou utilizar no meu dia-a-dia. Hehe

Comment: Se pudessemos dar um nome para esse if dos meses, poderiamos chamá-lo de `if from hell`

Comment: +1 pelo Mestre Yoda

Comment: Obrigado, meu caro padawan, que a força esteja com você.

Answer (score 18):

Condicionais são uma das maiores fontes de complexidade para o código. Um código com 1 condicional tem dois caminhos que o fluxo de execução pode tomar; um código com 2 condicionais em sequência tem 4 possibilidades e assim por diante. No entanto, seu programa vai precisar de alguma lógica condicional pra fazer algo útil o que indica que a melhor maneira de fazer a pergunta não é "porque ifs sao ruins" mas sim "como fazer meus condicionais da melhor forma".

Tem 2 pontos que eu vou discutir. O primeiro é a a **cegueira booleana** e o segundo é o **"expression problem"** (não sei se tem um nome em Português pra isso):

Um problema que você vai ter com ifs é que eles só conseguem fazer um decisões binárias, sobre expressões booleanas. Se o seu modelo tiver mais de dois casos para tratar então haverá uma perda de informação se você usar booleanos para representar seus dados. Por exemplo, suponha que eu tenha um programa com 3 estados possíveis: "Desligado", "Ligando" e "Ativado". Se nós usarmos um enum para representar o estado do programa e um `switch` para interpretar o estado, podemos tratar os três casos de forma limpa e também obtemos um aviso do compilador se esquecermos de tratar um dos casos (ou se um dos casos for redundante):

```
switch(estado){
   case DESLIGADO: print("A"); break;
   case LIGANDO: print("B"); break;
   case ATIVANDO: print("C"); break;
}
// se um dia eu adicionar um quarto estado na definição da enum,
// um bom compilador me avisa que é preciso atualizar essa parte do código
```

Usando ifs sobre o enum dá pra escrever algo bem parecido, apesar de perder um pouco da análise em tempo de compilação.

```
if(estado == DESLIGADO){
  print("A");
}else if(estado == LIGANDO){
  print("B");
}else if{estado == ATIVANDO){
  print("C");
}else{
  error();
  // Se eu adicionar um caso novo, vai dar um erro só em tempo de execuçao
  // mas é melhor que nada, né...
}
```

O problema maior é se você usar booleanos para codificar seu estado ao invés de uma enum.

```
bool desligado;
bool ativado;

// desligado=1 ativado=0 ==> DESLIGADO
// desligado=1 ativado=1 ==> ????
// desligado=0 ativado=0 ==> LIGANDO
// desligado=1 ativado=1 ==> ATIVADO

if(ativado){
  print("C");
}else if(desligado){
  print("A");
}else{
  print("B");
}
```

Esse código agora é uma chatice. Além de o compilador não ter como te ajudar se você resolver alterar o número de estados do modelo, agora nós temos 4 combinações de valores possíveis para as flags mas só 3 possibilidades válidas. Isso significa que o programa pode "engolir erros": por exemplo, se você setar ativado=true e desligado=true o seu programa vai considerar como se fosse ATIVADO ao invés de dar um erro como ele deveria. No final das contas, o verdadeiro problema aqui foi ter usado uma combinação de flags ao invés de enums - os ifs são só um sintoma disso.

---

Agora vou pro segundo ponto, que é o que a campanha do anti-if levanta.

Suponha que você modelou um sistema em que existem vários casos para os seus dados, várias ações que você pode fazer com os valores e cada combinação caso-ação vai fazer algo diferente. Como programar isso? Tem duas formas básicas:

A primeira é usando um switch dentro de cada função:

```
//pseudocódigo

function f(val){
  switch(val.caso){
    case A: print("F A"); break;
    vase B: print("F B"); break;
  }
}

function g(val){
  switch(val.caso){
    case A: print("G A"); break;
    case B: print("G B"); break;
  }
}
```

A segunda é usar dispatching dinâmico de métodos ou callbacks:

```
//pseudocódigo

class A:
  method f(): print("F A");
  method g(): print("G A");

class B:
  method f(): print("F B");
  method g(): print("G B");
```

Qual dessas duas formas é melhor? **Depende de como o seu programa vai evoluir no futuro!** Ás vezes vai ser melhor usar classes ao invés de ifs mas tem outras vezes que usar ifs (ou switch) é melhor mesmo.

- Na versão com switch é **fácil adicionar uma função nova** sem ter que mexer nas existentes, mas é **difícil adicionar um caso novo** à enumeração, já que você vai ter que mexer nos switchs de todas as funções.
- Na versão com classes é **fácil criar um caso novo** (basta criar uma classe nova) mas é **difícil adicionar um método novo** pois você vai ter que mexer na implementação de todas as classes existentes.

Um comentário ao lado: acho que uma das razões para ter tanta gente incentivando o uso de métodos ao invés de switch é que na maioria das linguagens de programação os "switchs" são mais fracos que as chamadas de métodos. Em linguagens de programação funcionais, como Haskell ou Ocaml, as enums podem armazenar dados adicionais (além da tag determinando qual é o caso) e existem uma sintaxe de pattern matching mais poderosa que o switch tradicional (faz um "desempacotamento" automático dos campos dependendo que qual caso você estiver tratando e não precisa ficar dando "break" no final de cada caso)

Comment: Essa resposta é muito boa.

Comment: +1 por ter explicado o que é e quais são os perigos da [Complexidade Ciclomática](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_ciclom%C3%A1tica) (apesar de não ter utilizado este termo)! :-P

Answer (score 12):

Li todas as respostas, e realmente a pergunta já foi respondida.

Contudo, apesar de a pergunta deixar claro que seu interesse é do ponto de vista de orientação a objetos, acredito ser relevante acrescentar ao tópico outra razão pela qual temer construções `if`, que está relacionada com a arquitetura interna de alguns processadores.

Se levarmos em conta um computador Intel compatible (x86, x64), o `if` faz com que parte do serviço realizado pelo [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline) do processador seja perdido, uma vez que o salto condicional para outro endereço fará com que as instruções já decodificadas tenham que ser descartadas.

Por exemplo, no código abaixo, algumas instruções do `Bloco B` podem ser decodificadas pelo processador, enquanto o resultado da pergunta do `if` não fica pronto. Quando o resultado fica pronto, caso a resposta à pergunta seja falsa, o processador deverá realizar um salto para o `else`, efetivamente executando o `Bloco C`, cujas instruções não estavam em seu [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline). Assim, o trabalho já realizado para decodificar as instruções do `Bloco B` é perdido.

```
Bloco A
if (Pergunta) {
    Bloco B
} else {
    Bloco C
}
```

Esse tipo de problema é muito comum, e a maioria dos processadores modernos conta com diversas técnicas de [predição de salto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor), para tentar "prever" de antemão, se o resultado à uma pergunta será verdadeiro ou falso antes de iniciar o processo de decodificação do [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline).

Ainda assim, esse processo nem sempre consegue acertar a previsão com 100% de precisão, especialmente se a `Pergunta` estiver diretamente relacionada com o resultado de alguma operação aritmética no final do `Bloco A`.

Nesses casos, o [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline) pode até não ser descartado por completo, mas pode sofrer [stall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_stall), que faz com que seu funcionamento pare momentaneamente, esperando pelo término da instrução da qual ele depende.

O capítulo 7 do livro [The Software Optimization Cookbook - Second Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0971288712) discute uma série de técnicas e artifícios para lidar com essas questões.

Apesar de nem sempre ser possível utilizar algumas das técnicas do livro em linguagens como C#, Java, VB, a ideia geral do funcionamento do [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline), [predição de salto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) e [stall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_stall) se aplica da mesma forma a todas elas.

Apenas para concluir, saindo do contexto da arquitetura computacional, e voltando ao contexto de orientação a objetos da pergunta, percebi que, apesar de utilizar uma funcionalidade análoga, nenhuma resposta explicitamente cita o uso de [padrões de projeto](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software) como o [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), para remover construções `if`, como explicado no livro [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201633612) ("livro do GOF", como também é conhecido).

Answer (score 9):

O excesso de IF ou CASE aumenta sim a complexidade de código mas metodologias Orientadas a Objeto, por exemplo, podem simplificar o código quando você usa Herança e Polimorfismo. A diferença é que em vez de ter muitos IFS e CASES você passa a ter "muitas classes". Ter muitas classes não é ruim pois cada uma delas terá uma função específica e a semântica do seu código pode ficar mais clara. Além disso você poderá usar "Design Patterns" para promover as boas práticas de Design deixando seu código mais compreensível.

Veja por exemplo o caso de implementar um Aplicação para manpular documentos de diversos tipos. Uma abordagem puramente estruturada exigiria uma série de IFs ou CASEs para lidar com os diferentes tipos de documentos.

Por outro lado numa abordagem Orientada a Objetos podemos usar o padrão *Factory Method* para encapsular toda a lógica referente a criação de um dado tipo de documento e o **Polimorfismo** implementado pela infraestrutura da Linguagem de programação utilizada será responsável por fazer grande parte do trabalho de decisão da sua série de IFs e CASEs da abordagem estruturada. O ganho na clareza do código é inestimável pois um simples diagrama de Classes UML mostra a implementação e não é necessário visualizar o código detalhadamente para entender como o sistema funciona.

[image: Diagrama UML para nossa Aplicação]

Veja que neste exemplo a criamos apenas uma classe concreta MeuDocumento mas poderíamos ter diversos classes concretas diferentes e a aplicação continuaria a conhecer **apenas** a Abstração Documento.

Cada *Design Pattern* **ajuda a melhorar** uma parte específica de uma aplicação este é um exemplo simples com um único Pattern. Numa aplicação podemos usar dezenas de Design Patterns colaborando entre si.

Comment: Trabalhar no Design para melhorar a aplicação retirando o excesso de IFs e CASEs exige um entendimento dos  [Design Patterns](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern) e pode ser feito no Refactoring do código que já está funcionando sem a devida otimização.

Comment: Seria possível elaborar um pouco mais. A resposta parece boa, mas falta dizer mais o porque de cada caso ou mostrar as diferenças.

Comment: Bem melhor agora!

Answer (score 9):

Particularmente, achei duas maneiras interessantes de eliminar if's desnecessários.

### 1 - Polimorfismo

Primeiro um exemplo usando uma técnica antiquada envolvendo inúmeros if's e de difícil manutenção:

```
public class Animal {
    private String tipo;
    public Animal(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
    public void fazerBarulho() {
        if(tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("Cachorro")) {
            System.out.println("Au! Au!")
        }
        else if(tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("Gato")) {
            System.out.println("Miau!")
        }
        else if(tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("Galinha")) {
            System.out.println("Pó pó pó");
        }
    }
}
```

O código poderia ser simplificado com ajuda do polimorfismo, da seguinte maneira:

[image: polimorfismo]

```
public class Teste {
    Animal cachorro = new Cachorro();
    Animal gato = new Gato();
    Animal galinha = new Galinha();

    System.out.println(cachorro.fazerBarulho());
    System.out.println(gato.fazerBarulho());
    System.out.println(galinha.fazerBarulho());
}
```

Quando chama o método `fazerBarulho()` é chamado o método do objeto em questão, até mesmo por que não há como implementar o método na interface, logo o resultado do código acima seria:

> Au! Au!
> Miau!
> Pó pó pó

### 2 - Remodelando sua estrutura

Outra opção de reduzir os if's é remodelando sua estrutura. Segue um exemplo:

Imagine que você desenvolveu um software para sua empresa que seria um configurador de produtos, estilo aqueles de carros que você monta o seu.

Na parte de acessórios você fez algo assim:

[image: acessorios]

E você deixa os usuários escolherem os acessórios livremente.

Um belo dia você está alimentando seu banco de dados com novos acessórios e você recebe a informação do seu chefe que dois deles são incompatíveis entre si. Digamos `direção hidráulica` e `direção elétrica`. Você não pode deixar o cliente escolher os dois, logo, você deverá restringir isso no seu software.

Você decide por não remodelar sua estrutura e prefere fazer um pequeno "conserto" na sua programação:

```
Map<Integer, JCheckBox> checkBoxesAcessorios = new HashMap<>();

.
.
.

//digamos que o id dos acessórios incompatíveis são 74 e 75

//nesse if voce verifica se o acessorio eh o 74 e desmarca o 75, caso ele esteja marcado
if(acessorio.getId() == 74) {
    checkBoxesAcessorios().get(75).setSelected(false);
}
//nesse if voce desmarca o 74 caso o acessorio seja o 75
else if(acessorio.getId() == 75) {
    checkBoxesAcessorios().get(74).setSelected(false);
}
```

Não é surpresa para ninguém que esse código funcionará bem, e a tarefa  terá sido cumprida.

Entretanto, suponha que para sua infelicidade, cada dia que se passa começam a surgir mais e mais produtos que se encaixam na condição de incompatibilidade e você se vê obrigado a encher seu código com zilhares de if's, a primeira coisa que se percebe nesse ponto é que você se tornou escravo do seu código, pois toda vez que novos acessórios com incompatibilidade são inseridos você deve alterá-lo.

Cansado de mexer no seu código a cada novo acessório você decide remodelar sua estrutura, já que seu programa não deve apenas atender as necessidades que ele atendia quando ele foi projetado, o programa precisa evoluir para atender novas necessidades e isso exige um remodelagem. Uma opção seria alterar sua classe Acessório, deixando ela assim:

[image: acessorios com grupo]

Foi adicionado um atributo `grupo` que indica quais acessórios pertencem a um mesmo grupo e portanto não podem ser usados ao mesmo tempo. A parte do código que possuía os inúmeros if's ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
desmarcarChecksIncompativeis(acessorio.getGrupo());
```

E uma possível implementação do método acima seria:

```
public void desmarcarChecksIncompativeis(int grupo) {
    for(Acessorios a: this.getAcessorios()) {
        if(a.getGrupo() == grupo) {
            checkBoxesAcessorios().get(a.getId()).setSelected(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Modelando dessa maneira, não mais é necessário alterar o código para indicar quais acessórios são incompatíveis, basta cadastrá-los no banco de dados dentro de um mesmo grupo, então toda vez que um acessório for selecionado os acessórios incompatíveis serão removidos.

Comment: O polimorfismo já foi citado na resposta aceita, mas preferi citá-lo novamente pois quis criar um exemplo mais enxuto. O segundo ninguém havia citado.

Comment: Acho que é pq o 2o. ñ elimina o `if`:) Só está em outro lugar. É como o exemplo do `for` do Luiz Vieira, não eliminou o `for`, só trocou de lugar. Eu tinha votado nela por causa da parte do polimorfismo clássico. De uma certa forma o segundo é um polimorfismo do objeto mas que só dá certo em situações específicas. Não acho que o objetivo de eliminar o `if` seja este. De qualquer forma dá para fazer de forma mais flexível com *lambda*. Deu até vontade de responder pq ainda ñ tem resposta com isto. Mas não é a solução correta. A sua resposta, do carlosrafaelgn e do hugomg deveriam ter + votos.

Comment: @bigown sim, eu _apenas_ troquei o `if` de lugar, se tiverem 1000 acessórios que a condição deve ser checada o `if` será executado 1000 vezes, mas ele só é escrito na linha do código uma única vez, isso junto com o novo campo `grupo` do objeto refletem em uma manutenibilidade infinitamente melhor pois o código não precisará mudar cada vez que o BD for atualizado ;-) Sobre o lambda, estou meio desatualizado e não sei exatamente do que se trata, se compartilhar uma resposta pode atualizar quem estiver perdido assim que nem eu :)

Answer (score 7):

Isso depende bastante das linguagens. [Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2919/1589) a outra pergunta, eu dei um exemplo de como `if`s podem ser abusados em linguagens que suportam Interfaces (como C#, Visual Basic.NET e Java).

Em outros casos, eu diria que você deve evitar `if`s longos, pois eles tiram a linearidade do código. Se você tem uma função de 50 linhas, em que na quinta linha você tem um `if` que tem 20 linhas, e depois um `else` com outras 20, é bem possível que isso possa ser otimizado, por exemplo. Se as operações são semelhantes, será que você não pode aplicar um uso de interfaces nesse meio e simplesmente remover as condições? (Vide meu exemplo na outra resposta, caso não fique claro)

Outro caso, como mencionado em outra resposta, é quando existem correntes longas de `if-else-if`. Nesses casos, um `switch` (ou, em linguagens funcionais, `pattern match`) é algo que se adequa melhor às suas necessidades.

Eu, como prática pessoal, não uso `if`s no meu código (exceto quando meu líder me obriga). Eu sempre uso o operador condicional ternário `?:` disponível em quase todas as linguagens. A principal vantagem é que ele sempre retorna um valor, o que te dá belas vantagens de código:

```
if (condição) {
  valor = 1;
} else {
  valor = 2;
}
```

Contra:

```
valor = condição ? 1 : 2;
```

**Resumindo**: Como eu disse no segundo parágrafo e em um comentário, o problema do `if` é o mesmo do `goto`: Perder a linearidade do código. Quando você tem blocos de `if` (e / ou `else` / `else-if`) muito grandes, se perder no código simulando o fluxo de execução é muito fácil.

Comment: "Eu, como prática pessoal, não uso ifs no meu código[...]". Fiquei curioso quanto a isso. Como você faria, por exemplo, em uma situação onde um objeto pode ter dois estados? Tipo, conectado e desconectado. E determinadas operações nesse objeto dependem dele estar conectado ou não. Você faria duas classes Conectado/Desconectado e herdaria de uma interface em comum?

Comment: @FranciscoJunior Boa. Como só tem dois casos (conectado e desconectado) eu provavelmente usaria o operador condicional ternário (chamando uma função se necessário). Se eu tivesse mais casos (conectado, desconectado e limitado), provavelmente usaria um Switch / Pattern Match ou Array / Dictionary como citado na resposta do PauloRoberto. (**Resumindo**: O problema não são condições, e sim perder a linearidade do código. Eu não gosto de ter que "ignorar" mais de 5 linhas pra imaginar o resultado de uma função, por exemplo.)

Comment: O `operador condicional ternário` é um if disfarçado. O que a pergunta espera é uma maneira de mudar a estruturação do código para não ter que fazer tantos testes nas variáveis no decorrer do código. Isso é possível através da programação orientada a objetos (POO) e como fazer isso usando POO será a resposta correta.

Comment: @Math Não é _só_ um `if` disfarçado de função. Ele é uma expressão, enquanto o `if` é só um controle de fluxo. Ele sempre retorna um valor enquanto o `if` só muda o caminho que o programa toma (assim como um `goto`) baseando-se em uma condição. Se você quer alternativas POO ao seu problema, eu coloquei isso no primeiro parágrafo. Mas a pergunta pede, no título, uma explicação de "porque em algumas situações ifs são considerados ruins". E isso eu respondo claramente no resumo.

Answer (score -5):

Rapaz, isso é muito relativo, por exemplo ao invés de escrever

```
<?php
$str = 'f';
if ($str == 'a') {
    echo 'Letra A';
} else if ($str == 'b') {
    echo 'Lebra B';
}
// ....
```

É o mais indicado

```
<?php
switch ($str) {
    case 'a': echo 'Letra A';
    case 'b': echo 'Letra B';
    // .....
}
```

As boas práticas é com a experiência e um certo "Feeling" do negócio

Comment: Não é sobre isso que a pergunta está falando. Apesar de haver uma semântica ligeiramente diferente, `switch` é praticamente um if. Além do mais, falta explicar porque um melhor que o outro. Esta resposta não responde a pergunta.

Comment: Um switch é mais facilmente vetorizável pelo compilador ou interpretador. Certamente um switch com 26 opções indo de 'A' a 'Z' é melhor que um if/else com 26 itens, mas o melhor mesmo é uma construção no estilo vetor de handlers -- mais eficiente e mais bonito.