# Validação de objeto de negócio evitando/reduzindo uso de if's e else's

Tags: java, jpa, design-pattern

Tenho um problema onde possuo três tipos de funcionário(FuncionarioA, FuncionarioB, FuncionarioC), todos serão gravados numa tabela chamada Funcionario e seus respectivos relacionamentos, porém, estes tipos citados anteriormente, possuem validações diferenciadas entre si. Apenas com as annotations do JPA não consigo e gostaria de saber se há algum design pattern ou algo parecido para evitar  if's e else's para fazer as validações do caso de uso, estas por sua vez, serão retornadas ao ManagedBean para serem exibidas ao usuário.

Frameworks do projeto:
JSF 1.2;
EJB 3.0;
EclipseLink com JPA 1.0;

Servidor: jboss 5.1

Comment: Talvez essa pergunta pode ser de alguma ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4731/por-que-em-algumas-situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ifs-s%C3%A3o-considerados-ruins

Comment: Para construir o funcionário de acordo com o seu tipo, criei um builder com strategy, pois consigo criar um funcionário que eu quero, utilizando polimorfismo e hook methods. Acho que terei que adicionar um método de validação específico para cada tipo de funcionário em suas respectivas classes e antes de construir os mesmos, além de inserir na interface que todos implementam. Assim, além de construir o funcionário de acordo com o tipo chamando o método uma única vez, faço o mesmo com a validação.

Comment: @caioalx O critério para definir o tipo de funcionário é apenas um campo?

Comment: Exatamente. Se o mesmo é celetista, quadro permanente, surfista e etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você poderia usar um `Enum` que faça a validação ou retorne um validador para reforçar que cada tipo de funcionário implemente devidamente a validação.

Preparei um exemplo simples, abaixo...

## interface `FuncionarioValidator`

```java
public interface FuncionarioValidator {
    void validate(Funcionario f) throws Exception;
}
```

## Implementações dos validadores

```java
public class CeletistaValidator implements FuncionarioValidator {

    @Override
    public void validate(Funcionario f) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(f.getNome() + " -> " + getClass().getName());
    }

}

public class QuadroPermanenteValidator implements FuncionarioValidator {

    @Override
    public void validate(Funcionario f) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(f.getNome() + " -> " + getClass().getName());
    }

}

public class SurfistaValidator implements FuncionarioValidator {

    @Override
    public void validate(Funcionario f) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(f.getNome() + " -> " + getClass().getName());
    }

}
```

## Enum `TipoFuncionario`

```java
public enum TipoFuncionario {
    
    Celetista(new CeletistaValidator()), 
    QuadroPermanente(new QuadroPermanenteValidator()), 
    Surfista(new SurfistaValidator());
    
    private FuncionarioValidator validator;
    
    private TipoFuncionario(FuncionarioValidator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }
    
    public FuncionarioValidator getValidator() {
        return validator;
    }
    
}
```

## Exemplo de `Funcionario`

```java
public class Funcionario {
    
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    private TipoFuncionario tipo;
    
    public Funcionario(Integer id, String nome, TipoFuncionario tipo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    
    public TipoFuncionario getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

}
```

## Realizando a validação

Implementei um teste bem simples:

```java
public class FuncionarioTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        
        //cria lista de funcionários
        List<Funcionario> funcionarios = new ArrayList<Funcionario>();
        funcionarios.add(new Funcionario(1, "João", TipoFuncionario.Celetista));
        funcionarios.add(new Funcionario(2, "José", TipoFuncionario.QuadroPermanente));
        funcionarios.add(new Funcionario(3, "Maria", TipoFuncionario.Surfista));
        
        //valida todos
        for (Funcionario funcionario : funcionarios) {
            funcionario.getTipo().getValidator().validate(funcionario);
        }
        
    }

}
```

Resultado:

> João -> br.com.starcode.validacaoenum.CeletistaValidator
>
> José -> br.com.starcode.validacaoenum.QuadroPermanenteValidator
>
> Maria -> br.com.starcode.validacaoenum.SurfistaValidator

## [Código disponível no GitHub](https://github.com/utluiz/java-playground/tree/master/random-code/src/main/java/br/com/starcode/validacaoenum)

Comment: Genial! O enum eu já tinha criado, mas nunca me passou pela cabeça em retornar um validador pelo mesmo.