# Validar com annotations objeto dentro de um método

Tags: java, design-pattern, validação, annotation

Tenho um JavaBean com diversos atributos, e que precisam ser validados.
Ele possui um atributo do tipo enum, e de acordo com o valor desse atributo, o objeto precisa de algumas validações específicas, e há validações que independem do valor do enum.

Eu achei uma resposta em outra pergunta muito interessante (link: [Validação de objeto de negócio evitando/reduzindo uso de if's e else's](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22184/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-objeto-de-neg%C3%B3cio-evitando-reduzindo-uso-de-ifs-e-elses) ), onde o próprio enum retorna um validador. E estava pensando que essa seria a melhor opção.

Então basicamente há um JavaBean, que possui um atributo enum. O enum tem um método getValidator que retorna um objeto validador que implementa uma interface Validator.

Mas no fim, as validações aconteceriam no método .validate da implementação do Validator:

```
public class CeletistaValidator implements FuncionarioValidator {
@Override
public void validate(Funcionario f) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(f.getNome() + " -> " + getClass().getName());
}}
```

Mas pelo que eu pude entender, nesse caso terei que fazer as validações dentro desse método validate() e utilizando métodos.
Eu gostaria de fazer as validações utilizando as annotations.

Eu pensei em criar mais um JavaBean para cada tipo de funcionário, e nesse novo JavaBean colocar as annotations, mas assim ficaria com muitas classes e confuso e parece não ser uma boa opção.

Então exemplificando de outra forma o meu problema. Suponhamos que eu tenha uma classe Funcionario, e existe o atributo TipoFuncionario, que é um enum com os valores celetista, quadro permanente, surfista. Se for um surfista, haverá validações mais especificas para os atributos de contato como email e telefone, se for um celetista há validações especificas de nome e documentos, mas todos seguem validações padrões de endereço. Gostaria de encontrar uma forma de implementar validações com annotations nesse caso, ou se a solução que pensei é aceitável.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, o que você está fazendo é reinventar a roda. Em uma linguagem orientada à objetos, supondo que você esteja usando algum modelo de persistência, me parece mais correto criar uma classe Funcionario e suas especializações, exemplo:

```
public class Funcionario implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    // Validações referentes aos campos de funcionários
}
```

E classe Surfista, por exemplo:

```
public class Surfista extends Funcionario implements Serializable { // Relacionamento um-para-um
    private Double tamanhoDaOnda;
    // Validações referentes aos campos de surfistas
}
```

Dependendo do projeto, vale a pena dar uma olhada no Hibernate Validator (http://hibernate.org/validator/) e no esquema de validações do JSF 2.2 (http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.com.br/p/validation-in-jsf.html).

Comment: Eu pensei em fazer utilizando herança, mas estou evitando pelos problemas que ela traz. Achei a solução apresentada no link que postei interessante e gostaria de usá-la, mas apenas não entendi como fazer no momento da validação para poder usar annotations, já que ela ocorre no método .validate().

Comment: O Hibernate Validator é justamente a implementação que estou utilizando.