# Design Patterns em C?

Tags: c, design-pattern

Iniciei o desenvolvimento de um sistema embarcado em C puro. O projeto requer uma documentação detalhada de software e hardware, além de utilizar os padrões de projetos recomendados.
É sabido que existem diversos padrões de projetos voltados para métodos, classes, pacotes e afins da programação orientada a objetos. O que existe a respeito do C? No meu caso irei criar os arquivos de cabeçalho .h e os arquivos de implementação propriamente dita .c.

Li em alguns locais que o que se tem de padrão para o C é a declaração das funções no início do arquivo e a implementação logo abaixo das declarações, ficando:

```
void funca1(int arg1, int arg2);
int funca2(bool arg1, int arg2);
...
void funca1(int arg1, int arg2){
// code here...
}

int funca2(bool arg1, int arg2){
// code here
}
```

É só isso mesmo que existe para o C?

Comment: A extensão usual para linguagem C é `.c` (e não `.cpp` como indicas).

Comment: @pmg foi um erro de grafia, o cpp é do C++?

Comment: É sim do C++ o `.cpp`. A ideia é teres as assinaturas das funções no `.h` e a implementação das mesmas no `.c`

Comment: A sua pergunta é muito boa, mas um tantinho ampla. Eu pensei em oferecer uma resposta, mas depois que comecei a escrever ela pareceu opinativa ("as minhas escolhas") e vasta. Eu sugiro que você crie perguntas para princípios específicos (esta atual, pode ser a respeito da motivação/finalidade/vantagem de usar/definir assinaturas/protótipos de funções).

Comment: Além disso, eu sugiro que você procure material usando a expressão "melhores práticas" (ou "best practices", se procurar em inglês) ao invés de "padrões de design". Vai te ajudar um bocado. Por exemlo, [este blog](http://www.embedded.com/collections/4398825/Best-practices-in-programming) tem muita coisa bacana bastante argumentável, como por exemplo [este artigo sobre 5 práticas comuns](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/best-practices-in-programming/4219722/Don-t-follow-these-five-dangerous-coding-standard-rules) (e a argumentação de como torná-las realmente melhores).

Comment: Eu entendo Luiz, nesse caso a necessidade é por conta de gerar a documentação do produto mesmo.

Comment: Ah, percebo o que quer dizer. Desculpe, não tinha entendido isso devido ao aparente foco nas assinaturas de funções. Bom, ainda assim tem muita coisa que se pode fazer a respeito: gráficos com a conexão entre os "módulos" do seu sistema, detalhamento das dependências entre as funções (quem chama quem), e por ai vai. Se eu conseguir bolar uma resposta eu ofereço-a depois. :)

Comment: @touchmx http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16204/101 esta minha resposta pode te interessar para reforçar e dar uma outra explicação que padrões são qualquer coisa reconhecida e recorrente, como diz a ótima resposta do Luiz Viera.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Como eu já comentei, essa é uma ótima pergunta, embora um pouco difícil porque pode ser abordada de algumas formas distintas. Há [uma pergunta muito similar (se não exatamente igual) no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112796/are-there-any-design-patterns-in-c). Eu não sei se você já a conhecia ou se inspirou nela, mas seguramente o conteúdo de lá também irá te ajudar.

### Sobre o uso de Padrões para Documentação

Como o próprio nome diz, os Padrões de Projeto (*Design Patterns*) são perfis de problemas recorrentes acompanhados de abordagens de solução já bem utilizadas, testadas e avaliadas para os problemas que propõem resolver. Naturalmente o seu uso primordial (isto é, originalmente intencionado) é facilitar a solução de problemas recorrentes. Um projetista que estudou Padrões de Projeto e reconhece um problema já bem descrito pode rapidamente utilizar a melhor abordagem, e assim diminuir o acoplamento, facilitar a manutenção, etc, etc, etc.

Mas naturalmente os Padrões de Projeto também servem para auxiliar na documentação de sistemas. Afinal, se as soluções empregadas se tratam de *abordagens padronizadas* e *amplamente reconhecidas* pela comunidade, a mera menção delas já ajudará um bocado. Por exemplo:

> O jogo XXXXXX usa o [padrão *Bridge*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software)) na renderização dos obstáculos,
>   de forma a separar o desenho do formato (circular, triangular,
>   quadrilátero, etc) do traçado utilizado no desenho (contínuo, tracejado, pontuado,
>   piscante, etc).

Nesse cenário de exemplo, qualquer novo desenvolvedor que chega ao projeto *e já conhece* o padrão *Bridge* vai ter uma boa noção de como a implementação foi feita, e saberá que na necessidade de criar um novo formato (hexagonal, por exemplo) bastará herdar a classe base dos formatos para automaticamente ser capaz de reutilizar nele todos os traçados já existentes.

Pensando dessa forma, a dificuldade da documentação não está no padrão de projeto em si, mas na sua descrição formal e em seu reconhecimento por uma comunidade. Os [padrões de projeto do GoF](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padr%C3%A3o_de_projeto_de_software#Padr.C3.B5es_GoF_.28.27Group_of_Four.27.29.3B), por exemplo, foram criados e documentados em um formato padronizado que inclui as seguintes descrições:

- Nome. O nome do padrão projeto, que serve como um identificador único para referência facilitada.
- Intenção. O propósito desse padrão, isto é, por que ele existe, qual é a sua utilidade, que tipo de vantagens ele traz.
- Problema. O problema que o padrão se propõe a resolver. Essa descrição não inclui apenas texto, mas também diagramas, exemplos e o que mais for de ajuda para tornar o entendimento do problema amplo e generalizado (afinal, os problemas podem ser recorrentes independentemente do domínio do sistema).
- Solução. Como o padrão fornece a solução ao problema. Novamente, aqui também pode se incluir texto, diagramas e exemplos, com a intenção de descrever em detalhes como essa implementação ocorre.
- Participantes e Colaboradores. As entidades envolvidas na solução e como elas representam partes do problema. No GoF originamente se mencionavam as classes envolvidas, mas entidades podem ser entidades como quaisquer estruturas computacionalmente implementáveis na linguagem/tecnologia que se utiliza.
- Consequências. Descrição das possibilidades decorrentes do uso do padrão, incluindo problemas potenciais evitados, facilidades de evolução, interação com outros padrões, etc.

É minha opinião (e gostaria de deixar bem claro que essa parte é mesmo uma opinião, embora fundamentada em experiência) de que qualquer abordagem de projeto que sirva como solução e foi criada por você mesmo pode ser documentada de uma forma similar. É por isso que eu te sugeri em comentários para procurar por "melhores práticas". Melhores práticas não deixam de ser soluções padronizadas para problemas reconhecidos, comumente descritas textualmente e com exemplos de código.

De fato, o próprio GoF indica que elementos da abordagem orientada a objetos poderiam ser considerados padrões de projeto na linguagem C (texto em tradução livre da citação [nesta resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4112872/2896619)):

> "A escolha da linguagem de programação é importante porque ela
>   influencia o ponto de vista do programador. Nossos padrões assumem
>   linguagens com características do nível das em Smalltalk/C++, e essa
>   escolha determina o que pode e não pode ser implementado *facilmente*.
>   *Se assumirmos linguagens procedurais, poderíamos incluir como padrões
>   de projeto a "Herança", o "Encapsulamento" e o "Polimorfismo".* De
>   forma similar, alguns dos nossos padrões são suportados diretamente
>   por linguagens menos orientadas a objeto. CLOS tem multi-métodos, por
>   exemplo, que diminuem a necessidade de padrões como o Visitor."

<sub>Os itálicos são meus.</sub>

### Padrões Existentes em C

Certamente há padrões de projeto existentes para a linguagem C, bem documentados e amplamente conhecidos. Os mais populares são os do livro ["Patterns in C" de Adam Tornhill](https://leanpub.com/patternsinc) (que se chamava Adam Petersen antes de se casar e mudar de sobrenome). A resposta aceita da pergunta do SOEN que eu referenciei no começo tem links para capítulos do livro dele, mas eu sugeriria comprá-lo porque não é caro ($ 4,99 é o valor mínimo para a versão digital no site dele) e estimula o bom trabalho de pessoas como ele.

Nesse livro você encontra, por exemplo, o padrão [*First-Class ADT*](http://adampetersen.se/Patterns%20in%20C%201.pdf), que separa a "interface" (o que é publicamente acessível) da implementação de "objetos" (ponteiros para estruturas). A ideia é bem simples: você usa a características de poder declarar tipos incompletos na linguagem C para definir um ponteiro para a estrutura e fornece funções para alocar e desalocar a estrutura real, escondendo assim o acesso direto aos elementos da estrutura. Há também, por exemplo, o padrão [*States*](http://adampetersen.se/Patterns%20in%20C%202,%20STATE.pdf), que utiliza uma tabela de transição de estados para evitar a repetição de (potencialmente longas) estruturas de decisão todas as vezes que a variável de estado precisa ser verificada. Este padrão, apesar de ser documentado para utilização em C, é muito relacionado com o mesmo problema que pode ocorrer em C++, [como já bem documentado aqui no SOPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4731/por-que-em-algumas-situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ifs-s%C3%A3o-considerados-ruins).

Como eu já opinei antes, eu acho que padrões de projeto não precisam incluir somente soluções a problemas de mais alto nível, mas também soluções reconhecidas que intencionam evitar problemas de implementação de baixo nível (erros de compilação, falhas em acesso a memória, dificuldades com tipos de dados, etc). Nesse caso, eu repito a sugestão que ofereci em comentários: melhores práticas são muito úteis quando documentadas, porque não apenas descrevem a abordagem idealizada como padrão para o time de desenvolvedores como também os motiva a pensar a respeito dos problemas potenciais em não se utilizá-las.

Exemplos notáveis (embora muitas vezes ainda discutidos) são [o uso de definições (`#define`) para evitar inclusão circular de cabeçalhos](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~kmammen/documents/c/howToPreventMultipleAndCircularInclusion.html), [o uso de `const` ao invés de `#define` para definir valores constantes](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/best-practices-in-programming/4219722/Don-t-follow-these-five-dangerous-coding-standard-rules), e também [evitar o uso de `scanf` para diminuir erros de invasão de memória](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17067360/2896619).

> P.S.: Note como na resposta do @pmg há o uso de um desses padrões
>   citados. O `#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED` serve justamente para evitar a
>   inclusão circular do cabeçalho. :)

Comment: Sua resposta é extremamente esclarecedora para mim. Sua abordagem me passa uma impressão de grande experiência e conhecimento na área de engenharia. Sou muito grato pelo seu tempo e resposta. Se fosse possível votava mil vezes em sua resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, mas uma vez só é suficiente. :) Fico feliz em ajudar.

Answer (score 8):

No que respeita a ficheiros de cabeçalho e ficheiros de código e localização dos protótipos, o mais cómodo é meter os protótipos no `.h` e incluir esse `.h` no `.c`. Assim só escreves cada protótipo apenas 1 vez ... e o compilador verifica se o protótipo bate certo com a definição quando compilar.

Por exemplo, o ficheiro de cabecalho "foobar.h"

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED
void foo(int);
int bar(void);
#endif
```

e o ficheiro de código "foobar.c"

```
#include "foobar.h"

int foo(int n) {
    return n + 42;
}
int bar(int n) {
    return n + 42;
}
```

Quando compilares "foobar.c" o compilador vai verificar as funções e dar erro (ou warning) porque o protótipo não bate certo com a definição.

Nota: configura o teu compilador para o máximo de warnings e tenta fazer código que compile com 0 warnings.

Comment: Excelente, bem resumido e com o suminho todo. Fazia apenas uma referência também as estruturas.

Comment: Nesse caso é somente isso que existe para o desenvolvimento em C e outras linguagens que utilizam o paradigma estruturado?