# IFs e Orientação a objetos - C#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Tenho uma dúvida sobre técnicas de como substituir o IF por polimorfismo.

Vou dar o seguinte exemplo:

Digamos que eu tenha as classes `ExecucaoIndividual` e `ExecucaoGeral`.

Para isso criei uma interface com o intuito de utilizar o padrão *strategy* que ficou assim:

```cs
interface IExecutor {
    void Executar();
} 

class ExecucaoIndividual : IExecutor {

    public void Executar() {
       //bla bla bla
    }
}

class ExecucaoGeral : IExecutor {

    public void Executar() {
        //bla bla bla
    }
}
```

Até aí beleza, mas na classe base onde vou verificar qual classe devo chamar (individual ou geral), qual seria a melhor abordagem para não ter que ficar utilizando:

```cs
IExecutor execucao;

if(determinadaCondicao)
  execucao = new ExecucaoIndividual();
else
  execucao = new ExecucaoFinal();

execucao.Executar();
```

Já vi alguns `Factories`, `Maps`, etc, mas nada que tirasse essa minha dúvida. Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Qual o problema com a abordagem que está utilizando atualmente?

Comment: Cara, eu imagino que não tenha o que fazer, pelo exemplo que você deu, terá que continuar com a condicional, para saber qual classe o objeto deverá ser instância...

Comment: Fico pensando se existe alguma abordagem melhor de se fazer isso :)

Comment: Acho que não. Depende muito do código. As respostas, creio, seriam opinativas.

Comment: BTW, nem sempre ifs são ruins: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4745/1745

Comment: Se você tiver muitos *Executor* e forem usados em várias classes, pode escrever algo do tipo de um *factory*. Você passa a condição e recebe a Executor. Terá os *if's* à mesma mas apenas em um só lugar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polimorfismo não se aplica aqui.

Polimorfismo acontece nas variáveis, nas instâncias.

Por exemplo:
 Tenho a classe `gato`, e a classe `cachorro`, ambas derivadas de `animal`. A classe animal tem uma propriedade `cor` e um método `alimentar()`.

Como `gato` e `cachorro` são animais, posso chamar `cor` ou `alimentar()` em um gato.

Agora, quando crio uma nova instância, não posso criar sem saber o tipo. Nem posso criar um `cachorro` como se fosse um `animal`.

No seu caso, o if está na outra "ponta" da lógica. É ele que determina o tipo da classe. E isso não pode ser feito de forma polimórfica.

- **Quando cria uma nova instância, você precisa definir o tipo**.
- **Quando for usar o objeto, você pode usá-lo como se fosse outro tipo, graças ao polimorfismo**.

Factories e outros servirão para centralizar essa decisão de qual tipo instanciar, mas no final, sempre haverá um `if` ou estrutura equivalente.

Comment: Obrigado, todas as respostas de vocês foram úteis. Eu estava procurando uma forma de abolir os ifs rsrs, mas não tem jeito.

Comment: Não existe. Mas o que é feito, e um item importante de arquitetura, é centralizar a criação destas instâncias. Procure por IoC (invertion of concern) ou DI (dependency injection), acho que vai te interessar.

Answer (score 2):

Neste caso use uma Fábrica. Uma classe com um método estático que retorna um IExecutor. Talvez seja algo do tipo

```
public static IExecutor GetBestExecutor(Condicao _condicao)
{
   switch(_condicao) 
   {
       case Condicao.Individual:
         return new ExecucaoIndividual();
         break;
       default
         return new ExecucaoGeral();
         break; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar uma *Factory* assim:

```cs
class ExecucaoFactory {

    public void IExecutor Criar(boolean condicao) {
        return condicao ? new ExecucaoIndividual() : new ExecucaoFinal();
    }
}
```

```cs
ExecucaoFactory factory = new ExecucaoFactory();
factory.Criar(algumaCondicao).Executar();
```

No fundo você está colocando o `if` (ou o operador ternário equivalente) dentro da factory, aonde a sua complexidade ficará encapsulada e concentrada em apenas um único lugar, simplificando possíveis alterações futuras que puderem vir a ser necessárias.