# Diferença de desempenho entre várias condições em um IF ou vários IF's separadamente?

Tags: java, desempenho, if

Durante uma alteração em um código-fonte, me deparei com a seguinte situação, desenvolvida por outro desenvolvedor:

```
if ( booleano1 || booleano2 || booleano3 )
{
    if( booleano1 )
    {
        //faz algo
    }

    if( booleano2 )
    {
        //faz algo
    }

    if( booleano3 )
    {
        //faz algo
    }
}
```

Claramente, a intenção do desenvolvedor era verificar se uma das condições era verdadeira antes de realizar os 3 `if` separadamente. A única justificativa que pude encontrar para ter sido implementado desta forma seria um ganho (insignificante?) de performance.
Portanto, minha dúvida é: existe alguma melhora de performance ao utilizar várias condições no mesmo `if` em relação a implementar vários `if` separadamente?

Comment: Isso tá com cara de neura de microotimizações hein

Comment: Pois é, na minha concepção, mesmo se houvesse um ganho, seria insignificante até por ser uma operação primitiva do Java, mas essa implementação me deixou com a dúvida se realmente existe alguma diferença.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Depende do que a expressão booleana faz. Se o desenvolvedor repetiu a lógica em cada IF o código pode ficar beeeem mais lento e sem necessidade. Já vi muito isso em nome de economizar uma variável.

Comment: Me parece um caso de um desenvolvedor cético. Afinal, essas linguagens de hoje em dia não são muito confiáveis. Vai que a variável muda de uma hora para outra sem explicação? Para garantir ainda mais eu faria assim: `if (booleano1 && booleano1)`. Sempre verifique duas vezes se quiser ter certeza. Melhor prevenir do que remediar.

Comment: @utluiz sério ?  (booleano1 && booleano1) ? mds kkk

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Pra ficar melhor só fazendo `booleano == true && booleano  == true`. Programador prevenido vale por dois. :D

Comment: @utluiz usa === para não fazer conversão de tipo uhauha

Comment: o que seria do mundo sem a ironia hahahahahaha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse código certamente tem um desempenho menor do que deveria. Não há razão alguma para existir o `if` mais externo, não muda lógica alguma, ou há ganho, pelo contrário, ele certamente fará comparações redundantes.

Se existisse código dentro deste `if` além dos três `if`s internos, aí até teria algum sentido lógico.

Se eles fossem separados, ou seja, se estivesse comparando apenas o `if` externo com o conjunto dos três `if`s internos executando separadamente ficaria complicado comparar porque eles estariam executando algo totalmente diferente. O `if` com operadores relacionais executará uma vez se um deles for verdadeiro. Se colocar os três `if`s cada um deles será executado dependendo da condição de cada um.

Se eles não executam a mesma coisa, ou seja, se não produzem o mesmo resultado, eles não podem ser comparados.

Se existisse uma situação em que pudessem o ganho seria mínimo ou inexistente. Poderia ser até que dependesse do compilador (até mesmo da versão dele), então não é algo que se pode afirmar, o que vale em um dia pode não valer no outro.

Não se preocupe com isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Complementando a resposta do bigown, em alguns cursos de informática  existe a disciplina de Complexidade de Algoritmos, nela você aprende a mensurar o quão custoso pode ser ou não uma lógica.
Se fosse ser colocada em cima desse código ele teria uma Complexidade Alta, além de desnecessária, pois:
É executada uma comparação que é novamente executada `if`à `if`
Caso nas comparações abaixo tivesse mais uma cláusula que verificasse um segundo valor e esse valor dependesse da ordem das validações feitas anteriormente essa lógica talvez possa ser aceitável, mas dessa forma gasta processos.

Comment: Você está falando especificamente da [complexidade ciclomática](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_ciclomática), certo?

Comment: Exatamente bigown

Answer (score 1):

O ganho de desempenho seria insignificante para seu caso , Não é recomendado o uso exagerado do `IFs`, pois ele torna seu código difícil de ler e de dar manutenção, logo não é uma boa prática. Pode aumentar a complexidade do código, aumenta a dificuldade no entendimento e na hora de fazer futuras manutenções.

Fonte:
[Por que em algumas situações if's são considerados ruins?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4731/por-que-em-algumas-situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ifs-s%C3%A3o-considerados-ruins)

Comment: Como diz a resposta do @bigown, não há ganho em nenhuma situação, pois o IF externo é logicamente redundante.