# É errado usar vários cases para a mesma ação no switch?

Tags: java, estilo-de-codificação, switch

É errado fazer isso com o `switch`? Eu programei assim com ele, está errado?

```
switch(estado){
case "AL":
case "BA":
case "CE":
case "MA":
case "PB":
case "PE":
case "PI":
case "RN":
case "SE":
//FAZ ALGO AQUI PARA TODOS OS CASES DO NORDESTE
break;
case "ES":
case "MG":
case "RJ":
case "SP":
//FAZ ALGO AQUI PARA TODOS OS CASES DO SUDESTE
break;
etc...
```

Comment: Então né... haha ai depende, eu acho estéticamente feio hehe então no meu caso eu prefiro usar if e comparações mesmo, mas vai do gosto de cada um =)

Comment: Normalmente o `switch` é uma má escolha. Mas para saber o que seria melhor no seu caso, você teria que dizer o que você quer fazer com esses estados.

Comment: setar uma cor diferente para cada região. Só isso.

Comment: Não chega a ser uma resposta, porém me parece que você está modelando regiões implicitamente através do seu *switch statement*.  Uma alternativa à sua solução seria incluir as regiões no modelo  (e.g., `enum Regiao`  com `NORDESTE`, `SUDESTE`, etc). Me parece mais limpo tratar 5 regiões do que um `switch` com todos os estados + DF.

Comment: @Matheus mas em questão de muitas validações, utilizar `if` não tornaria a execução mais lenta que a função `switch`? O `switch` possui a possibilidade de frear (break) o código caso o valor corresponda, já o `if` causaria um processamento desnecessário, pois se encontrei o que preciso não teria necessidade de continuar a processar. Ou o `if` também possui um break internamente?

Comment: Para casos simples pode usar [essa abordagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4744/91) vale para qualquer linguagem com algumas adaptações. Para usos mais complexos veja as demais respostas ;)

Comment: Em programação, assim como em qualquer outro aspecto da vida, uma coisa somente é errada se houver um motivo pelo qual ela é errada. Boa pergunta BTW.

Comment: @TiagoBoeing sim isso concerteza, por isso citei que vai do gosto de cada um =), se utilizarmos o else if tambem iremos parar de percorrer códigos desnecessários

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Não, isto é perfeitamente válido e usual se é o que deseja.

Se todos estes estados devem executar a mesma ação é assim mesmo que deve ser.

Em geral terá melhor performance do que fazer o mesmo com `if`, fora que faz mais sentido neste caso.

Eu só indentaria e alinharia um pouco melhor:

```
switch (estado) {
    case "AL":
    case "BA":
    case "CE":
    case "MA":
    case "PB":
    case "PE":
    case "PI":
    case "RN":
    case "SE":
        //FAZ ALGO AQUI PARA TODOS OS CASES DO NORDESTE
        break;
    case "ES":
    case "MG":
    case "RJ":
    case "SP":
        //FAZ ALGO AQUI PARA TODOS OS CASES DO SUDESTE
        break;
    etc...
}
```

Ou

```
switch (estado) {
case "AL":
case "BA":
case "CE":
case "MA":
case "PB":
case "PE":
case "PI":
case "RN":
case "SE":
    //FAZ ALGO AQUI PARA TODOS OS CASES DO NORDESTE
    break;
case "ES":
case "MG":
case "RJ":
case "SP":
    //FAZ ALGO AQUI PARA TODOS OS CASES DO SUDESTE
    break;
etc...
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/SwitchStyle.java).

Em um caso assim eu jamais trocaria tempo de compilação por tempo de execução. A lista é definida durante o desenvolvimento, finita e pequena e praticamente não tem alterações, então este é o correto. Eu até gosto de outras soluções apresentadas , mas não para este caso. É mais código, mais complexo, menos legível, menos performático, ou seja, é só para ser *clever* sem produzir vantagens.

Claro que pode-se criar uma abstração que trate o que cada estado deve fazer, mas isto geralmente deixa o código complexo, então só vale a pena se ele for complexo mesmo, e essa complexidade adicional sirva para ajudar gerenciar a complexidade geral.

Note que o controle do estado em si deve ser muito simples, o que fará terá que ser em classes específicas, afinal sempre pode se adicionar comportamentos novos que estão relacionados aos estados, mas que fazem parte de um subsistema diferente. Um é usado pelo marketing, outro para escrituração fiscal, etc.

Comment: +1, ps: Eu sou o unico que posiciono o break no alinhamento dos cases xD

Comment: ufa que bom. eu fiz assim e isso vai para produção. :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento É, não é comum, mas é válido, tem até algum sentido. O que eu queria mesmo é que não precisasse, deveria ter uma sintaxe diferente.

Comment: Depois de muito o Eclipse insistir, eu acabei por me acostumar a colocar os `case`s no mesmo nível do `switch`, mas fica muito mais legível com esse nível a mais

Comment: Também uso com o nível a mais. E o switch em cascata, quando bem usado, é uma ótima ferramenta. Vale lembrar que em muitas linguagens nem deve se comparar o `switch` com uma séries de `if ... else`, pois a implementação é muito diferente das duas estruturas.

Comment: Só pra deixar meus dois cents, eu uso em cascata também e quase sempre uso chaves xD

Answer (score 9):

## Abordagem com `Map`

Já que o seu propósito é setar uma cor diferente para cada região, então:

```
private static final Map<String, String> regioes = new HashMap<>(27);
private static final Map<String, Color> cores = new HashMap<>(27);

static {
    String[] norte = {"AM", "AP", "AC", "RO", "RR", "PA", "TO"};
    String[] sul = {"PR", "SC", "RS"};
    String[] sudeste = {"SP", "MG", "RJ", "ES"};
    String[] nordeste = {"BA", "SE", "AL", "PE", "PB", "RN", "CE", "PI", "MA"};
    String[] centroOeste = {"MS", "MT", "GO", "DF"};

    for (String s : norte) regioes.put(s, "norte");
    for (String s : sul) regioes.put(s, "sul");
    for (String s : sudeste ) regioes.put(s, "sudeste");
    for (String s : nordeste ) regioes.put(s, "nordeste");
    for (String s : centroOeste ) regioes.put(s, "centro-oeste");

    cores.put("norte", Color.RED);
    cores.put("sul", Color.GREEN);
    cores.put("centro-oeste", Color.YELLOW);
    cores.put("nordeste", Color.BLUE);
    cores.put("sudeste", Color.ORANGE);
}

private static Color corDoEstado(String sigla) {
    String regiao = regioes.get(sigla);
    return cores.get(regiao);
}
```

E então no seu código, você só tem que fazer isso:

```
algumaCoisa.setCor(corDoEstado(estado));
```

As vantagens dessa abordagem acima é que:

- O mapeamento é construído uma única vez no carregamento da classe.
- O mapeamento é reutilizável em outros locais, e você se livra de ter que repetir esse `switch` horroroso sempre que for lidar com estados.

## Abordagem orientada a objetos

Entretanto, essa abordagem ainda tem os seus problemas. O principal problema é que tudo isso se trata de [programação orientada a strings](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Gambi_Design_Patterns#Programa.C3.A7.C3.A3o_Orientada_a_Strings), por tratar essas coisas como strings e não como objetos que deveriam ser.

Assim, o ideal é fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
package com.example;
import java.awt.Color;

public enum RegiaoBrasileira {
    SUL(Color.GREEN),
    SUDESTE(Color.ORANGE),
    CENTRO_OESTE(Color.YELLOW),
    NORTE(Color.RED),
    NORDESTE(Color.BLUE);

    private final Color cor;

    private RegiaoBrasileira(Color cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

    public Color getCor() {
        return cor;
    }

    public static List<EstadoBrasileiro> getEstados() {
        return LocalizaEstados.porRegiao(this);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example;
import java.util.Locale;
import static com.example.RegiaoBrasileira.*;
import com.example.util.StringUtils;

public enum EstadoBrasileiro {
    RIO_GRANDE_DO_SUL("RS", SUL),
    SANTA_CATARINA("SC", SUL),
    PARANÁ("PR", SUL),
    SÃO_PAULO("SP", SUDESTE),
    RIO_DE_JANEIRO("RJ", SUDESTE),
    MINAS_GERAIS("MG", SUDESTE),
    ESPÍRITO_SANTO("ES", SUDESTE),
    BAHIA("BA", NORDESTE),
    SERGIPE("SE", NORDESTE),
    ALAGOAS("AL", NORDESTE),
    PERNAMBUCO("PE", NORDESTE),
    PARAÍBA("PB", NORDESTE),
    RIO_GRANDE_DO_NORTE("RN", NORDESTE),
    CEARÁ("CE", NORDESTE),
    PIAUÍ("PI", NORDESTE),
    MARANHÃO("MA", NORDESTE),
    PARÁ("PA", NORTE),
    AMAPÁ("AP", NORTE),
    ACRE("AC", NORTE),
    AMAZONAS("AM", NORTE),
    RONDÔNIA("RO", NORTE),
    RORAIMA("RR", NORTE),
    TOCANTINS("TO", NORTE),
    MATO_GROSSO("MT", CENTRO_OESTE),
    MATO_GROSSO_DO_SUL("MS", CENTRO_OESTE),
    GOIÁS("GO", CENTRO_OESTE),
    DISTRITO_FEDERAL("DF", CENTRO_OESTE),

    private final String nome;
    private final String sigla;
    private final RegiaoBrasileira regiao;

    private EstadoBrasileiro(String sigla, RegiaoBrasileira regiao) {
        this.sigla = sigla;
        this.regiao = regiao;
        this.nome = StringUtils.toTitleCase(name().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).replace("_", " "));
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }

    public RegiaoBrasileira getRegiao() {
        return regiao;
    }
}
```

```
package com.example;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class LocalizaEstados {

    private static final Map<String, EstadoBrasileiro> SIGLAS_POR_ESTADO = new HashMap<>(27);
    private static final Map<RegiaoBrasileira, List<EstadoBrasileiro>> ESTADO_POR_REGIAO = new HashMap<>(27);

    static {
        for (RegiaoBrasileira s : RegiaoBrasileira.values()) {
            ESTADO_POR_REGIAO.put(s, new ArrayList<>(9));
        }
        for (EstadoBrasileiro s : EstadoBrasileiro.values()) {
            SIGLAS_POR_ESTADO.put(s.sigla, s);
            ESTADO_POR_REGIAO.get(s.getRegiao()).add(s);
        }
        for (RegiaoBrasileira s : RegiaoBrasileira.values()) {
            ESTADO_POR_REGIAO.put(s, Collections.unmodifiableList(ESTADO_POR_REGIAO.get(s));
        }
    }

    private LocalizaEstados() {}

    static EstadoBrasileiro porSigla(String sigla) {
        return SIGLAS_POR_ESTADO.get(sigla);
    }

    static List<EstadoBrasileiro> porRegiao(RegiaoBrasileira regiao) {
        return ESTADO_POR_REGIAO.get(regiao);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.util;

class StringUtils {

    // Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086134/540552
    public static String toTitleCase(String input) {
        StringBuilder titleCase = new StringBuilder();
        boolean nextTitleCase = true;

        for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isSpaceChar(c)) {
                nextTitleCase = true;
            } else if (nextTitleCase) {
                c = Character.toTitleCase(c);
                nextTitleCase = false;
            }

            titleCase.append(c);
        }

        return titleCase.toString();
    }
}
```

Pode parecer um grande trabalho, mas:

- Você separa os conceitos de estados e regiões brasileiras de outras partes do código.
- Tudo isso é reutilizável.
- Se precisar alterar conceitos de estados e regiões brasileiras (por exemplo, acrescentar o conceito de capitais de cada estado), não é difícil alterar o enum.
- Conceitos de estados, regiões brasileiras e cores correspondentes deixam de poluir outras partes do código.

## Conclusão

Utilizar o `switch` é uma coisa horrorosa. Ele tende a poluir o código deixando-o confuso e difícil de ser mantido. O polimorfismo e o tabelamento adequado de dados em estruturas de dados adequadas são alternativas melhores a ele na maioria dos casos.

É verdade que isso tudo parece ser mais complicado do que usar um `switch`. O problema é que raramente você acaba usando apenas um e sim que você acaba usando dois, três, cinco, vinte vezes esses `switch`es espalhados em um monte de lugares do código.

Por isso, atente-se sempre ao caso do [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).

Comment: Sua conclusão me lembrou do movimento anti-`if`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado O movimento anti-`if` tem semelhanças com o anti-`switch`. Entrentanto, enquanto o `if` é muitas vezes de fato a melhor solução (mas nem sempre), o mesmo não ocorre com o `switch`, que quase nunca é a melhor solução.

Comment: Uau... :O. Nossa...assustador mas vou tentar implementar sim para entender melhor seu código.

Comment: Tem coisa no seu código que é muito avançado para mim :/

Comment: Se tiver dúvidas sobre algum dos conceitos ou palavras-chaves empregadas no código, @Aline, não tenha medo de fazer uma nova pergunta a respeito, sempre atenta às sugestões de duplicatas. Muitas coisas como "O que é enum", "O que é um Map" etc. já foram muito bem explicadas aqui no site. :)

Answer (score 6):

Como já respondido, é valido e funciona.

Minha opção geralmente é pela parte estética do código, nesse seu caso performance não é nem de longe uma preocupação.

Um outro approach(sim, com bem mais código pra escrever):

ActionProvider.java:

```
public interface ActionProvider {

    public void takeAction(String state);

}
```

NordesteActionProvider.java:

```
public class NordesteActionProvider implements ActionProvider {

    public void takeAction(String state) {
        System.out.println("Nordeste taking action");       
    }

}
```

SudesteActionProvider.java:

```
public class SudesteActionProvider implements ActionProvider {

    public void takeAction(String state) {
        System.out.println("Sudeste taking action");        
    }

}
```

StateStrategy.java:

```
public enum StateStrategy {

    NORDESTE(new NordesteActionProvider(), Arrays.asList("AL", "BA", "CE", "MA", "PB", "PE", "PI", "RN", "SE")),
    SUDESTE(new SudesteActionProvider(), Arrays.asList("ES", "MG", "RJ", "SP"));

    private List<String> states;
    private ActionProvider provider;

    StateStrategy(ActionProvider strategy, List<String> states) {
        this.states = states;
        this.provider = strategy;
    }

    public static Optional<StateStrategy> strategy(final String state) {
        return Arrays.asList(values())
                .stream()
                .filter(s -> { return s.states.contains(state); })
                .findFirst();               
    }

    public ActionProvider getActionProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

}
```

Utilizando:

```
String al = "AL";
StateStrategy strategy = StateStrategy.strategy(al).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Estado inválido"));
strategy.getActionProvider().takeAction(al);

String sp = "SP";
strategy = StateStrategy.strategy(sp).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Estado inválido"));
strategy.getActionProvider().takeAction(sp);
```

**Obs.:** da pra melhorar...

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, Tom, mas seria mais construtivo se você explicasse os conceitos empregados no seu código e por que ele é melhor ou pior do que a abordagem original.