# Como chamar métodos distintos em diversas condições do Switch Case?

Tags: java, switch

Tenho esse código, e gostaria de saber como chamar um método a partir do `switch...case`.

```
public static void opcoes(){

        System.out.println("Selecione o Algoritmo de Substituicao Desejado");
        System.out.println("1 - FIFO");
        System.out.println("2 - LRU");
        System.out.println("3 - Segunda Chance");
        System.out.println("4 - Otimo");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;

        switch(num){
            case 1: //// faz a chamada de método referente a FIFO

        }
```

Comment: `case 1: fifoMethod(); break; case 2: lruMethod(); break; ...` seria isso?

Comment: Isso mesm vlw!a

Comment: @user90625 editei o título de modo a refletir melhor o que realmente se deseja saber. Caso discorde, pode desfazer a edição ou tentar colocar um texto ainda melhor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você chama o código normalmente, como se estivesse no corpo de um método:

```
case 1:
  fifoMethod();
  break;
case 2:
  lruMethod();
  break;
...
```

Note que o `switch` exige que você tenha um ponto de destino da variável sendo "*switch*-ada". Esses pontos de destino são indicados pelos diversos `case`s. A priori, o comportamento é vazar de um caso para o seguinte, por isso é necessário colocar os `break`s para indicar que esse não é o comportamento desejado.

Note também que, caso não se encaixe em nenhum dos casos anteriores, você ainda tem o `default`.

```
switch (num) {
    case 1:
      fifoMethod();
      break;
    case 2:
      lruMethod();
      break;
    case 3: //...
      break;
    case 4: //...
      break;
    default:
      System.out.println(num + ", entrada inválida");
}
```

Podemos usar, para o seu caso, o `default` para tratamento de erros.

---

Leitura recomendada:

- [Crítica ao uso do switch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240459/64969)
- [Exemplo de como usar cascateamento corretamente no switch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240412/64969)
- [Como funciona o switch por baixo dos panos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176675/64969)
- [Qual diferença entre o return e o break em um switch case?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175459/64969) ; leitura válida da pergunta, respostas e comentários