# Protótipo de funções em C/C++

Tags: c, c++, funções, ponteiro, polimorfismo

Que tipos de funções são estas? O que estes protótipos podem fazer?

```
 /*1*/int func ( int (*x)(int,int) )


 /*2*/int func ( int x(int,int) ) 


 /*3*/int func1 ( int(fn)() )


 /*4*/int func2 ( int(*fn)() )
```

Este tipo de função é chamado de apontador para função? Como é utilizado e o porquê de ser utilizada.

```
typedef int cellulae_func(int, int);

void tabula(cellulae_func *cell, int lat, int alt);
```

Comment: Você tem referência da sintaxe de todos? Tem caso que eu desconheço.

Comment: Vi isto numa pagina a citar estes prototipos, porém so tinha mesmo isto. As 2 primeiras funções tem a duvida aqui [stackOverflEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851168/function-reference-paramater-pointer-vs-prototype-merely-style) Porem eu não consigo perceber mesmo assim com aquelas respostas e achei util colocar aqui.

Comment: Usar notação de ponteiro no nome da função ou usar o nome diretamente não faz diferença, e o compilador irá interpretar de ambas as maneiras.

Comment: @Isac falando da ultima função correto? Essa função apareceu num trabalho meu da faculdade e eu não percebi bem para que servia, terá algum uso bastante importante?

Comment: Refiro-me a todas, que são 2 multiplicadas em 4 devido às notações diferentes. O objetivo é mesmo funcionar como um callback (algo muito comum em linguagens com chamadas assincronas), embora em C não costume ser utilizada com o mesmo objetivo. Basicamente passa uma função que irá depois ser chamada. É com base nesse principio que consegue implementar polimorfismo em C puro.

Comment: Não consegue desenvolver isso numa resposta melhor e/ou citar algo para ler acerca disso? Parece que realmente estas funções são importantes no polimorfismo, nunca tinha ouvido falar e agora estou curioso relativamente a isso e de como funciona.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isto é **ponteiro para função**, então na forma apresentada, assim como um parâmetro pode receber uma referência para um objeto, o parâmetro pode receber uma referência para uma função.

Portanto C possui o que se chama [função de alta ordem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) ou de [primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101). Tratamos funções como se fossem dados.

Uma função já é naturalmente uma referência, afinal o acesso a ela se dá pelo endereço do início do código escrito nesta função, de forma análoga a um vetor que tem um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento dele. Isso vale para funções estáticas mesmo, mas neste caso o endereço está associado a um identificador existente no código e chama-se ele diretamente, não tem muito o que fazer com isto.

Mas é possível armazenar esse endereço em uma variável, ou mesmo passar como argumento para uma função que espera justamente um tipo que seja uma função. É a função mesmo, não é chamar uma função no argumento e passar o resultado dela, você passa ela. Claro que fala-se passar a função sem que esteja copiando seu código de um lugar para outro, copia-se só o endereço.

Então assim como um vetor de inteiros você pode ter um parâmetro mais ou menos como `int * x` quando é uma função que recebe um inteiro e retorna outra inteiro seria algo assim `int (*x)(int)`, sendo que o primeiro `int` indica que a função a ser recebida deve retornar um `int`, ela será armazenada em uma variável chamada `x` e receberá como argumento um `int`, conforme demonstrado pelo último `int`.

Eu descobri agora que podia usar a sintaxe sem o ponteiro, quando aprendi só podia usar assim e ainda preciso pesquisar se isso é padrão, mas acredito que sim pela fonte.

## `typedef`

Obviamente que uma [assinatura de função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) é um tipo da variável do parâmetro, sendo um tipo é possível criar um `typedef` para ele e tornar a sintaxe mais agradável.

Não precisa ser só em parâmetro, mas é onde se encaixa melhor. Poderia ser um membro de uma `struct`, tem casos interessantes para isto, e é uma forma de simular [polimorfismo dinâmico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101).

Exemplos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int func( int (*x)(int,int) ) { return x(20, 5); }
int func2( int x(int,int) ) { return x(20, 5); }
int func3( int(fn)() ) { return fn(); }
int func4( int(*fn)() ) { return fn(); }
typedef int cellulae_func(int, int);
int tabula(cellulae_func *cell, int lat, int alt) { return cell(lat, alt); }
int soma(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
int sub(int x, int y) { return x - y; }
int teste() { return 42; }
int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", tabula(soma, 20, 5));
    printf("%d\n", tabula(sub, 20, 5));
    printf("%d\n", func(soma));
    printf("%d\n", func2(soma));
    printf("%d\n", func3(teste));
    printf("%d\n", func4(teste));
    printf("%d\n", func4(soma)); //funciona, mas está errado
    int (*funcs[2])(int x, int y);
    funcs[0] = soma;
    funcs[1] = sub;
    printf("%d\n", func(funcs[0]));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CKT2xx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gumillym-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Pointer.c).

Note que passo os nomes estáticos das funções, e como esses nomes na verdade são ponteiros, estou passando o endereço delas. Do outro lado a variável que recebe esse ponteiro é usada para chamar a função usando a sintaxe dos parênteses. Ela não pode ser usada corretamente de outra forma, embora compiladores antigos ou com configurações selvagens permitam fazer estragos, e claro, com um *cast* tudo é permitido, mesmo que o resultado seja ruim.

O ideal é usar funções com assinaturas compatível, é comportamento indefinido usar uma inadequada, como demonstrado em uma das linhas.

As duas funções com nome `x` possuem a mesma assinatura, que é compatível tanto com a `soma` quanto a `sub` definidas mais abaixo. O `typedef` é compatível com a mesma assinatura. Os nomes poderiam ser diferentes, porque no fundo isso é apenas o nome da variável. As com nome `fn` possuem outra assinatura.

## Uso

A vantagem de ter isso é que podm configurar dinamicamente o que executar em determinado contexto. Que é o tal do [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101) (pelo menos uma forma dele). E é um [substituto do `if`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4731/101) em muitos casos, já que as funções podem ser colocadas em uma vetor ou outra estrutura de dados, como demonstrei acima no exemplo. Então sempre que alguma **ação** precise configurada sob demanda, conforme a necessidade do momento, este tipo de função é interessante.

É muito usado como [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101), onde você chama um algoritmo que em determinado momento precisa executar algo que ele ainda não sabe o que é, ou seja, ele responde a algo configurável pelo chamador. Então pense em *handlers*, *events*.

O próprio C tem algoritmos que esperam um *callback*, por exemplo o [`qsort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) onde você diz como ele deve executar a comparação de dados para classificar da forma como deseja, portanto pegando o dado específico, decidindo se fará algo operação extra com o dado, como por exemplo dar um *upper*, se será crescente ou decrescente.

A criatividade permite fazer composições diversas, poderia por exemplo criar um dicionário com (ponteiros para) as funções como valores dele e de acordo com algo digitado pelo usuário ou obtendo a informação de outra forma em tempo de execução chamar a função adequada, o que é muito parecido com o que uma linguagem com bastante dinamicidade e tendo um [`eval()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101) permite fazer.

Se for algo estático pode ser uma [*jump table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table).

Uma aplicação como é a chama [*lazy evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), onde você define o que deseja fazer, mas não quer que seja feito naquele momento, então você "passa o código" para algum lugar e no momento adequado o código é chamado.

## Limitação

C não possui sintaxe de *lambda* que poderia declarar a função no local que precisa. Algo assim não pode:

```
printf("%d\n", tabula((int x, int y) => x + y, 20, 5));
```

C também não tem um mecanismo próprio de captura de váriaveis do escopo atual para carregar junto com a função passada como parâmetro, algo que outras linguagens possuem, mas nada impede de você criar manualmente essa capacidade, só não é conveniente.

## Exemplo

O exemplo mais óbvio de uso é com algoritmos de classificação onde precisa dizer qual é o critério do que é menor do que o outro, até para decidir a chave exata ou se a ordem deve ser crescente ou decrescente. Por isso a função [`qsort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) padrão do C já recebe uma função como parâmetro. Em C++ isso é muito mais eficiente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(const void* left, const void* right) { return (*(int*)right - *(int*)left); }
int main() {
    int (*cmp) (const void* , const void*) = &compare;
    int array[] = {1, 8, 0, 4, 6, 5, 1, 6, 9, 7};
    qsort(array, 10, sizeof(int), cmp);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hF9qDE). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/swjpxchs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/QuickSortExample.c).

Exercício: isso gera uma [classificação estável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325088/101)? A pergunta é uma pegadinha.

## C++

Este mecanismo não deveria ser usado em C++, a não ser por compatibilidade, há muito tempo ela tem bibliotecas que lidam com isso de forma melhor, e desde 2011 possui [*lambdas* e *closures*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101). E até alguns usos específicos o C++ tem solução melhor.

## Assembly

Veja como fica depois de compilado pelo GCC (outros compiladores são, teoricamente, menos eficientes):

```assembly
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
  mov edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
  add eax, edx
  pop rbp
  ret
func:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  mov esi, 5
  mov edi, 20
  call soma
  pop rbp
  ret
func2:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 16
  mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
  mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
  mov esi, 5
  mov edi, 20
  call rax
  leave
  ret
tabula:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 16
  mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-12], esi
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-16], edx
  mov ecx, DWORD PTR [rbp-16]
  mov edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
  mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
  mov esi, ecx
  mov edi, edx
  call rax
  leave
  ret
main:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  mov edx, 5
  mov esi, 20
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:soma
  call tabula
  mov eax, 0
  call func
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:soma
  call func2
  mov eax, 0
  pop rbp
  ret
```

Melhor visualmente [no **Compiler Explorer**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/af35LF).

Dá para notar que a chamada sofre indireção e possui instruções mais complexas. O que talvez não seja tão óbvio é o acesso extra à memória e isto sim pode ser mais lento e faz mais diferença que algumas instruções a mais. E dá pra ver que tudo que é definição de tipos e contratos é jogado fora.

Answer (score 5):

Entretanto lembrei me de uma situação comum onde isso é utilizado e que provavelmente ajuda também a contextualizar, que é numa ordenação.

Assim como o @Maniero já explicou isso são ponteiros para funções, sendo que o nome tanto pode estar com ou sem notação de ponteiro que o compilador irá tratar de igual forma.

Por isso estas duas são iguais:

```
 /*1*/int func ( int (*x)(int,int) )
 //                   ^--

 /*2*/int func ( int x(int,int) ) 
 //                  ^--
```

Imagine que você tem um bubble sort para ordenar um array de inteiros:

```
void bubble_sort(int arr[], int tamanho) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < tamanho - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                int temp =  arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mas agora gostava de conseguir utilizar outros tipos sem ser apenas inteiros. Como irá fazer a comparação ? A comparação depende intrinsecamente do tipo e ainda se torna pior quando consideramos tipos que o programador pode criar com `struct`. Logo é impossível de você conseguir saber de antemão como comparar.

Em vez disso você recebe uma função que sabe comparar dois elementos e retorna:

- `< 0` quando o primeiro elemento é menor
- `0` quando são iguais
- `> 0` quando o primeiro elemento é maior

O próprio [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) que existe na biblioteca standard também recebe uma função para comparar. Veja um exemplo de uma função de comparação de inteiros para o `qsort`:

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b){
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

E agora quando chama o `qsort` passa a função como argumento:

```
qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
//                                ^--- aqui
```

Assim o `qsort` chama a sua função sempre que tem de comparar dois elementos no array e fazer a respetiva ordenação.

Então neste exemplo do bubble sort podemos fazer o mesmo, receber uma função para comparar cada elemento. Isto tem algumas implicações em relação aos parâmetros deste `bubble_sort`:

- O array tem de passar a ser um `void*` para apontar para qualquer tipo em memória
- É necessário também saber quantos bytes ocupa um tipo em memória para sabermos quantos bytes andamos para a frente sempre que queremos ir para o próximo elemento
- É também preciso receber a função que sabe comparar dois elementos

Com isto a nova assinatura da função pode ser:

```
void bubble_sort_generico(void *arr, int tamanho, int bytes_elem, int comparador(void*, void*) );
//                    ponteiro de função identico ao que tem na pergunta ----^
```

Agora a implementação fica mais complexa porque lida com `void*` e cada avanço no array tem de ser feito em `x` bytes que corresponde à quantidade de bytes que cada elemento tem:

```
void bubble_sort_generico(void *arr, int tamanho, int bytes_elem, int comparador(void*, void*) ){
    int i, j, tamanho_bytes = tamanho * bytes_elem;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho_bytes - bytes_elem; i += bytes_elem) {
        for (j = 0; j < tamanho_bytes - i - bytes_elem; j += bytes_elem) {
            void *ptr_elem1 = arr + j;
            void *ptr_elem2 = arr + j + bytes_elem;

            if (comparador(ptr_elem1, ptr_elem2) > 0){ //chamar o comparador
                char temp[1024];
                memcpy(temp, ptr_elem1, bytes_elem);
                memcpy(ptr_elem1, ptr_elem2, bytes_elem);
                memcpy(ptr_elem2, temp, bytes_elem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cada um dos `memcpys` corresponde à atribuição simples que antes era feita com `int temp =  arr[j];`. Como cada elemento pode ter vários bytes não existe forma de fazer uma atribuição simples e por isso a solução é copiar byte a byte até perfazer todos os bytes que fazem um elemento. Por simplicidade utilizei o [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) mas também poderia ser feito manualmente com um `for`.

A instrução `comparador(ptr_elem1, ptr_elem2)` que está dentro do `if` é a que chama a função recebida como parâmetro para fazer a comparação, passando dois ponteiros como argumentos.

O comparador pode ser uma cópia do que mostrei para o `qsort` mas ajustado aos tipos que a função espera:

```
int comparador (void *a, void *b){
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

Note que não utilizei `const void*` por simplicidade mas faria mais sentido claro, pois não é suposto a função de comparação alterar nada.

Vale relembrar que esta implementação pode ser melhor em alguns aspetos, mas tentei manter simples uma vez que o próprio conceito de funcionar para tudo com `void*` já tem tendência a ser complexo o suficiente. Esse também foi o motivo pelo qual optei por um dos algoritmos de ordenação mais simples.

A chamada no `main` seria assim:

```
int main() {
    int nums[] = {37, 2, 59, 1, 19, 3, 14};
    int tamanho = sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]);
    bubble_sort_generico(nums, tamanho, sizeof(int), comparador);
```

Agora a diferença é que também consegue ordenar strings por exemplo se passar uma função que consiga comparar duas strings:

```
int comparador_nomes(void * a, void* b){
    char **nome1 = (char**)a;
    char **nome2 = (char**)b;
    return strcmp(*nome1, *nome2);
}

int main() {
    char *nomes[] = {"joao", "filipa", "rita", "ana", "marcos"};
    int tamanho2 = sizeof(nomes) / sizeof(nomes[0]);
    bubble_sort_generico(nomes, tamanho2, sizeof(char*) , comparador_nomes);
```

Note que fiz a comparação dos nomes com base no [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

[Veja estes dois exemplos no Ideone](https://ideone.com/BfLSpm)

Como nota final, se olhar para a assinatura do `qsort` [em algumas das implementações](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c.html), vê algo semelhante aos exemplos que colocou:

```
typedef int (*__compar_d_fn_t) (const void *, const void *, void *);

void _quicksort (void *const pbase, size_t total_elems, size_t size, __compar_d_fn_t cmp, void *arg) {
//                                                                   ^-- função aqui
```

A diferença é que eles fizeram um [`typedef`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/stdlib.h.html#__compar_d_fn_t) para ser sintaticamente mais simples de escrever a função.