# Porque usar implements?

Tags: java, android

Qual a diferença entre usar

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

e

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
```

Estive fazendo um curso de Android e meu professor falou que o **implements** apenas ajuda deixar o código limpo sem se fazer necessário usar o `OnClickListener` no meio do código.
Será que é somente isto?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O propósito do `implements` **não é deixar o código mais limpo**, é apenas uma palavra reservada que diz que a sua classe está implementando uma interface, ou seja, sua classe agora é do tipo que ela implementou, com isso vem o que costumamos chamar de "Contrato", que é um jeito de dizer que a classe que implementa a interface é obrigada a implementar todos os métodos que a interface declarou.

Analisando seu caso. Em:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Você está criando uma classe anônima que deve seguir o contrato imposto pela interface OnClickListener.

Em :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
```

Você faz com que a sua classe MainActivity implemente a interface OnClickListener.

Em ambos os casos você vai precisar sobrescrever o método `onClick(View v)`. Obviamente, no primeiro caso você vai precisar fazer isso dentro da sua classe anônima e no segundo caso ele ficará dentro da sua classe MainActivity.

Se isso vai deixar o código mais limpo ou não, depende, ele pode sim fazer isso caso você tenha inúmeros botões que podem possuir algo em comum sendo então vantagem que todos eles chamem o mesmo método `onView()` dentro da sua classe MainActivity, assim:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Entretanto, não faz muito sentido que vários botões façam exatamente a mesma coisa, por isso que eu disse que ele pode ser usado quando possuem funções similares, mas fazendo dessa forma será necessário verificar dentro do método implementado qual foi o botão que chamou, sendo assim geralmente dentro desse método você terá um `switch` ou vários `if`s.

Ao ponto que, se a sua classe não implementasse ela você seria obrigado a "replicar" o código para todos os seus botões. Assim:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    //faça alguma coisa
});
```

Caso você tenha apenas um botão, a situação fica quase que empatada, pois você só implementará uma única vez. Para ambos os casos a diferença será mais a sua satisfação com cada uma das maneira de resolver o problema.

Mais detalhes do que é uma interface e por que elas são úteis podem ser encontradas nessa outra resposta: [Em orientação a objetos, por que interfaces são úteis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/3117)

Comment: É o que acontece, quando não uso o implements. No inicio até não me importava tanto, mas achei melhor justamente fazer este "contrato" como você disse. Isto ajudou um pouco. Agora entendi melhor esta questão.

Comment: @RogersCorrêa adicionei um link que explica um pouco melhor o que é uma interface, pois se eu explicasse isso aqui acho que ficaria muito abrangente, fora que é desnecessário pois já foi respondido no tópico linkado. Espero que você tenha entendido a real diferença entre os dois. Dizer que implements limpa o código é algo absurdo! Sua função é algo muito superior a isso, talvez limpar seja uma consequencia, mas chega a se tornar algo irrelevante perto do seu real propósito. Certifique que a dúvida foi sanada por completo, qualquer coisa peça mais detalhes em específico.

Comment: Muito obrigado Math. Vou olhar o link sim, conhecimento nunca é de mais.