# Adicionar objetos de tipos diferentes em um mesmo vetor

Tags: java

Não consigo adicionar a classe `Video` dentro do vetor.

```
public class SongDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Playlist lista = new Playlist();
        Musica num1 =new Musica("Agua de beber","Antonio Carlos Jobim","Astrud Gilberto", 140);
        Musica num2 =new Musica("O mar serenou","Candeia"," Clara Nunes", 179);
        Musica num3 =new Musica("Rapaz Folgado","Noel Rosa"," Martinho da Vila Mart'nália",180);

        Video num4 = new Video("Musica"," Despacito", " Luis Fonsi",5926796,280);

        lista.add(num1);
        lista.add(num2);
        lista.add(num3);
        lista.add(num4);


        lista.print();

    }
    public static class Playlist{

        private Musica []musicas;
        private int cont;

        public Playlist(){
            musicas = new Musica[1000];
            cont = 0;
        }
        public void add(Musica a){
            if(cont==musicas.length){
                System.out.println("ERROR: playlist atingiu sua quantidade máxima de itens.");
            }
            musicas[cont]= a;
            cont++;
        }
        public void add(Video b){
            if(cont==musicas.length){
                System.out.println("ERROR: playlist atingiu sua quantidade máxima de itens.");
            }
            musicas[cont]= b;
            cont++;
        }
        public Musica get(int i){
            if(cont> i){
                return musicas[i];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        public void print(){
            String result="Total de Musicas e Videos Alocados = "+cont+"\n";
            for(int i =0; i <cont; i++){
                result+=( i +" => "+musicas[i]+"\n");
            }
            result+="Tempo Total da PlayList: "+formatoTotalTempo();
            System.out.println(result.toString());
        }
        public int totalTempo(){
            int totalTempo=0;
            for(int i =0; i <cont; i++){
                totalTempo+=musicas[i].getDuracao();
            }
            return totalTempo;
        }

        public String formatoTotalTempo(){
            return formatoTempo(totalTempo());
        }
    }

    public static class Musica{

        public String nome;
        public String interprete;
        public String compositor;
        public int duracao;

        public Musica(String musicaNome,String interprteNome,String compositorNome,int tamanhoDuracao){
            this.nome=musicaNome;
            this.interprete=interprteNome;
            this.compositor=compositorNome;
            this.duracao=tamanhoDuracao;
        }

        public void setNome(String musicaNome){
            nome=musicaNome;
        }

        public String getNome(){
            return nome;
        }

        public void setInterprte(String interpreteNome){
            interprete=interpreteNome;
        }

        public String getInterprete(){
            return interprete;
        }

        public void setCompositor(String compositorNome){
            compositor=compositorNome;
        }

        public String getCompositor(){
            return compositor;
        }

        public void setDuracao(int tamanhoDuracao){
            duracao = tamanhoDuracao;
        }
        public int getDuracao(){
            return duracao;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return"Nome: "+getNome()+", Interprete:"+getInterprete()
                +", Compositor:"+getCompositor()+", Duracao: "+formatoTempo(getDuracao());
        }
    }
    public static class Video{
        String titulo;
        String assunto;
        String canal;
        int visualizacoes;
        long duracao_video;

        public Video(String tituloNome,String assuntoNome,String canalNome,int visualizacoes_video, long tempo_video){
            this.titulo = tituloNome;
            this.assunto = assuntoNome;
            this.canal = canalNome;
            this.visualizacoes = visualizacoes_video;
            this.duracao_video= tempo_video;
        }
        public void setTitulo(String tituloNome){
            titulo = tituloNome;
        }

        public String getTitulo(){
            return titulo;
        }
        public void setAssunto(String assuntoNome){
            assunto = assuntoNome;
        }

        public String getAssunto(){
            return assunto;
        }
        public void setCanal(String canalNome){
            canal = canalNome;
        }

        public String getCanal(){
            return canal;
        }
        public void setVisualizacoes(int visualizacoes_video) {
            visualizacoes = visualizacoes_video;
        }
        public int getVisualizacoes() {
            return visualizacoes;
        }
        public void setDuracao_video(long tempo_video) {
            duracao_video = tempo_video;
        }
        public long getDuracao_video() {
            return duracao_video;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return"Titulo: "+getTitulo()+", Assunto:"+getAssunto()+", Canal:"+getCanal()+
                    ", Visualizações: "+getVisualizacoes()+" Duração do video:"+formatoTempo(getDuracao_video());
        }

    }
    public static String formatoTempo(long tempo){
        int hora = 60;
        int minuto = 60;
        long h= tempo /hora;
        long m= tempo % minuto;
            return String.format("%02dh %02dmin", h, m);
    }

}
```

Comment: Isso não vai funcionar pq vc está tentando adicionar um `Video` em um array de `Musica`. Como as duas classes não tem relação nenhuma entre si, seus tipos são incompatíveis e não é possível colocar uma em um array que só tem a outra. Crie um outro array só para `Video` (na verdade, tem outras soluções, como refatorar as classes, criar uma interface `Playable`, por exemplo, para qualquer tipo de mídia "tocável", etc). Mas por ora, ter outro array deve bastar...

Comment: Hkotsubo, como faço para criar um vetor generico para as duas classes musica e video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que `Musica` e `Video` são classes diferentes que não tem relação nenhuma entre si. Por isso, ao tentar colocar um `Video` em um array de `Musica`, dá erro de compilação. Existem algumas alternativas para resolver esse problema.

*Obs: eu criei cada classe em um arquivo `.java` separado, por isso no meu código abaixo elas não são `static`. Talvez você tenha colocado tudo em um arquivo só "para facilitar", mas criar classes aninhadas [tem usos bem específicos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) que não parece ser o caso aqui. Então sugiro que separe cada classe em seu próprio arquivo `.java`.*

---

#### Usar outro array para `Video`

Isso é uma solução que não requer alteração nas classes `Musica` e `Video`. Basta manter um array separado para cada uma delas. Como você está controlando a quantidade de músicas com outra variável, vai precisar de mais uma para os vídeos também (e mudei o nome dos contadores para algo mais significativo).

```
public class Playlist {
    private Musica[] musicas;
    private Video[] videos; // novo array só para vídeos
    // manter um contador para cada tipo de mídia
    private int qtdMusicas;
    private int qtdVideos;

    public Playlist() {
        musicas = new Musica[1000];
        videos = new Video[1000];
        qtdMusicas = 0;
        qtdVideos = 0;
    }

    public void add(Musica a) {
        if (qtdMusicas == musicas.length) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: playlist atingiu sua quantidade máxima de músicas.");
        }
        musicas[qtdMusicas] = a;
        qtdMusicas++;
    }

    public void add(Video b) {
        if (qtdVideos == videos.length) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: playlist atingiu sua quantidade máxima de vídeos.");
        }
        videos[qtdVideos] = b;
        qtdVideos++;
    }
}
```

Obviamente que será preciso adicionar um método `getVideo`, e eu também mudaria o nome do método `get` atual para `getMusica`. O método `print` também deverá percorrer o array de vídeos logo depois do *loop* já existente no array de músicas.

Mas essa solução não é muito boa, pois duplica muito código: o algoritmo para adicionar, obter e imprimir músicas e vídeos é praticamente o mesmo. E se futuramente você quiser adicionar uma outra classe (por exemplo, `Filme`), terá que duplicar código novamente.

Talvez seja melhor generalizar a solução, mas isso exigirá uma alteração nas classes.

---

#### Generalizando...

Se você quer que sua `Playlist` tenha tanto músicas quanto vídeos, pode fazer com que ambas as classes `Video` e `Musica` compartilhem alguma característica que permita agrupá-las. No caso, ambas podem ser "tocadas" em um *player* de mídia. Então eu posso criar uma [interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/112052) que represente esta característica:

```
// representa qualquer coisa que pode ser "tocada" em um player
public interface Playable {
    public String getNome();
    public int getDuracao();
}
```

No caso, a interface `Playable` representa "algo que pode ser tocado em um *player*". Eu também defini os métodos `getNome()` e `getDuracao()`, mas repare que esses métodos não tem código. A interface só define *o que* um `Playable` faz, mas não *como* isso é feito.

Agora basta fazer com que `Musica` e `Video` sejam "coisas que podem ser tocadas em um *player*". Em outras palavras, ambas as classes devem implementar a interface `Playable`:

```
public class Musica implements Playable {
    // o resto da classe permanece igual
}
```

Como a classe `Musica` já possui os métodos `getNome()` e `getDuracao()` (e eles retornam respectivamente uma `String` e um `int`, tal como definido na interface), não é preciso fazer mais nada. Já a classe `Video` precisará de algumas adaptações, já que ela não possui esses métodos (abaixo coloquei apenas os trechos que mudei):

```
public class Video implements Playable {
    // mudei a variável duracao_video, pois é redundante (ela faz parte de Video, então claramente é a duração do vídeo)
    int duracao; // mudei para int, o tempo é em minutos, não precisa de long

    public Video(String tituloNome, String assuntoNome, String canalNome,
                 int visualizacoes, int tempo) {
        ....
        this.duracao = tempoVideo;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNome() {
        return this.titulo; // o nome do vídeo é o seu título
    }
    public void setDuracao(int tempo) {
        duracao = tempo;
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuracao() {
        return this.duracao;
    }
}
```

Mudei algumas coisas: como o tempo está em minutos (pelo que entendi), não precisa usar um `long`. Um `int` suporta até [pouco mais de 2 bilhões](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE), o que é suficiente para qualquer vídeo.

Também mudei o nome de `duracao_video` para `duracao`. Se a duração pertence à classe `Video`, é redundante dizer que esta é a duração do vídeo. Outro ponto é evitar `nomes_de_variaveis_assim`, já que a [convenção do Java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) é usar `nomesDeVariaveisAssim`.

---

Bom, agora que tanto `Musica` quanto `Video` são `Playable`, podemos mudar nosso array:

```
public class Playlist {
    private Playable[] items;
    private int qtdItens;

    public Playlist() {
        items = new Playable[1000];
        qtdItens = 0;
    }

    public void add(Playable item) {
        if (qtdItens == items.length) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: playlist atingiu sua quantidade máxima de itens.");
        }
        items[qtdItens] = item;
        qtdItens++;
    }

    public Playable get(int i) {
        if (qtdItens > i) {
            return items[i];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        String result = "Total de Musicas e Videos Alocados = " + qtdItens + "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < qtdItens; i++) {
            result += (i + " => " + items[i] + "\n");
        }
        result += "Tempo Total da PlayList: " + formatoTotalTempo();
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }

    public int totalTempo() {
        int totalTempo = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < qtdItens; i++) {
            totalTempo += items[i].getDuracao();
        }
        return totalTempo;
    }

    public String formatoTotalTempo() {
        return formatoTempo(totalTempo());
    }
}
```

Repare que agora eu só trabalho com `Playable`, ou seja, o array vai aceitar qualquer classe que implemente a interface `Playable`. Então eu posso adicionar `Musica`, `Video` e qualquer outra classe que eu criar futuramente (desde que ela implemente `Playable`).

---

#### Próximos passos

Isso é apenas uma introdução e serve como os primeiros passos para modelar melhor suas classes. Mas sugiro estudar a fundo [polimorfismo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1031273), modelagem de classes e o próprio mecanismo de interfaces e classes abstratas do Java. É algo amplo demais para abordar aqui, então deixo apenas mais uma dica "bônus".

Em vez de um array, você pode usar [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), pois assim você não precisa ficar controlando a quantidade de itens, já que a própria lista aumenta seu tamanho conforme a necessidade. A classe modificada ficaria assim:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Playlist {
    private List<Playable> items;

    public Playlist() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<>(); // não precisa dizer o tamanho, a lista controla isso para você
    }

    public void add(Playable item) {
        if (this.items.size() == 1000) { // se quiser, ainda pode limitar a quantidade máxima (opcional)
            System.out.println("ERROR: playlist atingiu sua quantidade máxima de itens.");
        }
        this.items.add(item);
    }

    public Playable get(int i) {
        if (i > this.items.size()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.items.get(i);
    }

    public void print() {
        String result = "Total de Musicas e Videos Alocados = " + this.items.size() + "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.items.size(); i++) {
            result += (i + " => " + items.get(i) + "\n");
        }
        result += "Tempo Total da PlayList: " + formatoTotalTempo();
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }

    public int totalTempo() {
        int totalTempo = 0;
        for (Playable item : items) {
            totalTempo += item.getDuracao();
        }
        return totalTempo;
    }

    public String formatoTotalTempo() {
        return formatoTempo(totalTempo());
    }
}
```

Outro detalhe é que se você usar o método `get`, irá obter um `Playable`, e para saber se ele é uma música ou um vídeo, terá que usar `instanceof` e fazer o *cast*:

```
Playable item = lista.get(0);
// testar o tipo de Playable retornado
if (item instanceof Musica) {
    Musica musica = (Musica) item;
    // usar a Musica
} else if (item instanceof Video) {
    Video video = (Video) item;
    // usar o Video
}
```

Comment: Eu estava refatorando o código do Bruno mas aí a página foi atualizada e já tinha a sensacional explicação do hkotsubo :D  
De qualquer forma a solução que eu estava elaborando está aqui https://github.com/joellobo/stackoverflow/blob/master/364318/src/com/stackoverflow/SongDriver.java

Comment: Agradeço ao hkotsubo e ao Joel lobo, são profissionais que fazem com que tenhamos prazer em aprender programar  , vocês deram explicações perfeitas, aprendi muito com vocês, abrigado amigos, meu sonho é chegar no nivel de conhecimento de vocês e poder ajudar outros ..

Comment: Amigos só mais uma pergunta, eu quero implementar uma maneira de aumentar o tempo do vídeo em porcentagem, EX: If(vizualizacoes < 1000) o tempo é o mesmo , else If(visualizacoes > 1000 && vizualizacoes < 10000) aumento em 2% o tempo, duracao= tempo_video *(2/100), minha duvida é onde implemento, posso colocar de ntro do setDuracao na classe Video.

Comment: Ok Obrigado pela atenção.