# Problemas com herança múltipla e uso de interface

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, interface

Estou criando um simples sistema de banco (estudando), existe uma classe Conta com informações básicas de cadastro, e uma classe Sistema que gere todas as contas. Eu pretendo criar uma classe `ContaDiretor` que deverá estender de `Conta` (pois é uma conta) e de `Sistema` (pois ele deve ter acesso a métodos/atributos exclusivos da classe `Sistema`).

```
package Conta;

import Banco.Cliente;
import Banco.Data;

public class Conta {

    public int numero;
    protected double saldo;
    public String extrato[] = new String [100];
    public Cliente titular = new Cliente();
    public Data DataDeAbertura = new Data();

    public void depositar (double saldo){
        this.saldo += saldo;

    }

    public double getSaldo(){

        return saldo;
    }



    protected boolean podeSacar(double valor){

        if (saldo < valor)
            return false;
        else
            return true; 

    }

    public void sacar (double valor, Conta conta){
        if (podeSacar(valor)) {

            saldo -= valor;
            System.out.println("Novo Saldo: ");
            System.out.print(conta.getSaldo());
            System.out.println("");

        }    
        else 
            System.out.println("Saldo indisponível");

    }



    public void transferencia (Conta c2){

    }

    public void getExtrato () {

        for (int i = 0; i < extrato.length; i++) {
            if (extrato[i] == null){
                break;
            }
            else
                System.out.println(extrato[i]);

        }



    }

    public void setExtrato(String nome, String atividade, double valor) {

        String extrato = nome + " " + atividade + " " + Double.toString(valor);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.extrato.length; i++) {
            if (this.extrato[i] == null) {

                this.extrato[i] = extrato;
                break;
            }

        }


    }
    public void setExtrato(String nome, String atividade, double valor, String nome2) {

        String extrato = nome + " " + atividade + " " + Double.toString(valor) +" para "+ nome2;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.extrato.length; i++) {
            if (this.extrato[i] == null) {

                this.extrato[i] = extrato;
                break;
            }

        }


    }

    public boolean contaequals(Conta a){

        return (this.titular.login == a.titular.login);        
    }
}

    package Banco;

import Conta.Conta;

public class Sistema{

    public Conta contas[] = new Conta[100];
    public Conta contaPublic = new Conta();

    private String nomeBanco = "Banco do Brasil"; //O diretor deve ser o único capaz de alterar o nomeBanco
    private int totalContas = 0; //O diretor deve ser o único capaz de receber totalContas

    public String getNomeBanco() {
        return nomeBanco;
    }

    public void adicionaConta(Conta conta){

        this.contas[totalContas] = conta;
        totalContas++;


    }


    public Conta getConta(int pos) {
        return contas[pos];
    }

    public Conta[] getContaVetor() {//retorna o vetor inteiro
        return contas;
    }


}
```

Conheço muito pouco de interface, eu tentei criar uma, porém descobri que todos os atributos de uma interface são final (não são modificáveis).

Se eu crio na interface os métodos abstratos como `setNomeBanco` e `getTotalContas` como `ContaDiretor` irá alterar os atributos que só existem em `Sistema`?

Não quero deixá-los public (`totalContas` e `nomeBanco`) pois quero que apenas `ContaDiretor` possa receber e alterar eles respectivamente.

Como `ContaDiretor` irá herdar os métodos e atributos das classes Conta e Sistema ao mesmo tempo?

Segue abaixo o rascunho da classe `ContaDiretor` e interface `SistemaInterface`:

```
 package Conta;

import Banco.InterfaceSistema;

public class ContaDiretor extends Conta implements InterfaceSistema{
    public static String nomeDoBanco;

    public void setNomeDoBanco(String nome) {
        this.nomeDoBanco = nome;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getNomeBanco() {

    }



}

    package Banco;

import Conta.Conta;

public interface InterfaceSistema {


    public String getNomeBanco();

    public void adicionaConta(Conta conta);

    public Conta getConta(int pos);

    public Conta[] getContaVetor();




}
```

Comment: Tente com composição, talvez resolva. Recomendo a [leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11380/77268)

Comment: Java não tem herança múltipla. Você pode extender de apenas uma classe. Interfaces são contratos onde se definem os métodos a serem implementados pelas classes que vão executar o comportamento definido pela interface. [Mais sobre interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html).

Comment: `ContaDiretor` é uma `Conta` que é gerenciada pelo `Sistema`. Não faz sentido conta ter funcionalidades do sistema. Qual é o enunciado do problema? Com essa informação ficará mais fácil te ajudar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem vários problemas nesse código, inclusive conceituais. Um deles começa pelo nome das coisas, um muito importante é que parece que existem de fato objetos que são `Conta` e objetos que são `ContaDiretor`, isto não parece certo, pelo menos pelos nomes e maneira de usar. Se esta classe `Conta` for abstrata e não puder ter objetos dela aí eu acho que pode fazer sentido, ainda não garanto, só posso garantir conhecendo o problema em detalhe, e aí esta interface parece fazer menos sentido ainda, embora possa ter e não estar na claro na pergunta.

Esse `contaequals` faz menos sentido ainda, não só pelo nome fora de padrão, mas principalmente porque provavelmente está querendo sobrescrever o [método `equals()` que todo objeto tem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html), seria bom estudar isso antes de tentar implantar algo deste tipo.

Tem métodos que não deveria estar aí. Tem gente que gosta disto, mas extrato é algo separado da conta. Conta é conta, cuidar de um extrato é algo que pode acontecer de formas variadas e mudar, e ter alternativas, e pode não poder fazer em certas situações. Enfim, não é responsabilidade da conta cuidar disto. O tipo `Conta` tem que ter meios de dar informações necessárias para gerar um extrato mas não cuidar dele. Nem os dados do extrato deveriam estar aí.

Na classe `Conta` você tem uma lista de de contas e permite adicionar algo ali? Isto não faz o menor sentido, ainda mais do jeito que foi implementado. Uma conta deve ter dados de **uma** conta, se fosse sobre uma lista de contas a classe deveria chamar `Contas` ou até outro nome mais significativo, e aí, claro, não deveria ter dados da conta individual.

Não gosto e muita gente diz que é bem errado o uso de *getters* e *setters* desta forma. Parece que eles existem pra seguir receita de bolo que alguém (que provavelmente não sabia o que estava dizendo) disse que deveria fazer assim. A pessoa não sabe bem porque está fazendo isto e saber porque (de verdade, não superficialmente) é mais importante que saber o que fazer.

Os métodos misturam responsabilidades e trata de IO em uma classe de negócios, isto não faz sentido. E mesmo o que estes métodos fazem são coisas estranhas.

Curiosamente se não fosse OO não precisaria pensar em nada dessas coisas.

Eu sei, é só um exercício, mas parece ser um exercício de OOP, e OOP é justamente montar um objeto de forma que faça sentido. Programar orientado a objeto não é jogar um monte de código seguindo umas regrinhas, é organizar o código de um jeito que resolva um problema da melhor forma possível. O que muita gente não entende é que OO é entender o problema e passar para o código de forma que seja mais fácil visualizar tudo como realmente é e ser fácil mexer no futuro. Se não fizer certo é melhor nem fazer desta forma. Está criando complexidade no código para zero benefício. Na verdade costuma haver malefício. É necessário profundo entendimento de computação, de engenharia de software e se debruçar sobre o problema a ser resolvido até entendê-lo com propriedade, coisa que raramente as pessoas fazem, elas "sempre" entendem errado, porque nem sempre o problema é tão aparente como ele realmente é, principalmente se confiar no usuário que não costuma entender o que de falo ele faz ali. Há um problema organizacional que impede o software ser bom se o desenvolvedor não perceber isso. Pior ainda quando o problema é artificial, aí vai sair errado e a pessoa vai aprender fazer algo torto a primeira vez e fará mais torto ainda as próximas. Você faz o que você treina, se treinar o erro é isto que fará sempre.

[O que você chama de atributo na verdade se chama campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). Eu sei você aprendeu assim, e é o que estou falando, é comum ensinarem errado. E interfaces não tem campos, ou atributos como você chamou (atributos até existem nela, mas não é isso que você pensa que é, então pra todos efeitos considere que não tem, é algo menos importante e mais acadêmico saber que ela tem atributos de verdade, será útil um dia quando quiser se aprofundar mas não agora). Por isso treinar demais pode ser um problema, porque pode estar treinando o erro.

> Se eu crio na interface os métodos abstratos como `setNomeBanco()` e `getTotalContas()` como `ContaDiretor` irá alterar os atributos que só existem em `Sistema`?

Me parece que essa interface tem a ver com a classe `Sistema` e não `ContaDiretor`, parece que está querendo enfiar ela lá de qualquer jeito mesmo sem ter um motivo para fazê-lo. Não que eu esteja dizendo que a interface deveria existir, pelo contrário, parece que não precisa, mas pode ser só porque a pergunta não deixa claro isso. Só use algo que possa justificar (com propriedade) porque está criando aquilo. Na pergunta não parece precisar. Na verdade não sei se deveria ter a classe `Sistema` (talvez, só não estão tão claro assim, nesta forma). Pode ser que precise de uma outra classe parecida com essa.

Quando uma interface tem `Interface` no nome já indica que tem algo muito errado aí. [Interfaces são contratos com capacidades de um objeto fazer algo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/101). Veja [Como e quando usar Interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101) e [Princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101).

> Como `ContaDiretor` irá herdar os métodos e atributos das classes Conta e `Sistema` ao mesmo tempo?

Não vai, não faz o menor sentido fazer isto. `ContaDiretor` não é um `Sistema`, na verdade sequer deve ser composto por um `Sistema`, salvo entendimento errado que a pergunta não deixou claro.

Um erro colateral, que para um exercício não é grave, mas é bom saber o certo, é que [valores monetários não pode ser do tipo `double`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Outro item colateral é que se você tem um `if` que dentro só tem um `return true` ou `false`, deveria eliminar o `if` e fazer a expressão booleana direto no `return`.

Comment: Agradeço por ter respondido, estou lendo hoje pela primeira vez, esse projeto é um tanto que antigo.
A solução que encontrei foi criar um package para contas (creio eu) e mudar algumas variáveis para protected. Eu nem sabia o que era uma interface na época, terminei esse mini-banco com umas 12 classes fora a parte gráfica. Criei uma interface funcionario para classes como contaDiretor e contaGerente (que acessavam menus diferentes). Confesso que muito dos erros que você apontou eu não corrigi e nem percebi que existiam. Vou reabrir esse projeto para realizar essas alterações.